# Fans don't wake up after suspend

Tags: suspend, fan

the title says almost everything.

If i suspend my ubuntu 12.04 on a compaq 615 laptop, on wake up everthing works perfectly apart from the fact that the fans don't wake up, cpu heats and upon reaching 90°C somehow triggers the fans to start. (idles at around 59°C).

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue. Try a live boot and see if the same thing occurs. If it does, you might want to consider taking the computer to get repaired.

Comment: Check for a bios update

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your laptop because I have seen many cases where it becomes difficult to gain back your session after 'suspending' from terminal. Try cleaning your fans for one thing.

Comment: They are crystal clean and work perfectly when booting+shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but you could try using a 3.5.0 kernel.

I had a similar experience to you when using 3.19.0 kernels on as Asus X453M laptop, but no such problem when using 3.5.0 kernels.

(Unfortunately I would really prefer a 3.19 kernel, because it allows me to get two-finger scrolling which I can't get with the earlier kernel.)

## How to

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image-3.5
...

$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-54-generic     # or whatever
...
```

When your machine reboots, you will need to go to `Ubuntu (Advanced)` and arrow-down to reach the 3.5.0 kernel.

If the older kernel satisfied you, you could [make grub select it automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry).

Comment: Update: I have not been having this issue since I installed the kernel [linux-image-4.4.0-14-lowlatency](http://askubuntu.com/a/755547/133393)