# Permanent Windows share mounting

Tags: 14.04, mount, cifs, smb

As this is a very basic topic, I have read many documentation about it online and none of them seems to work, I have tried several ways but I want to know if anybody has been successful with this so far.

So here's my fstab entry:

```
//AAAAAA/BBBBBB/CCCCC /backup cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/XXXXX/.smbcredentials  0  0
```

I'm getting:

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

And I am sure the credentials are correct because when I change it I get a permission error.

Again, I have tried several changes including `sec=ntlm`, `gid`, etc., but didn't solve it for me.

Comment: Did you try changing the `iocharset` to `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: I just did, here's the result:

mount error(79): Can not access a needed shared library
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: try `cp1251` instead

Comment: seems like the majority of the interwebz find this to be a hostname issue.  make sure you type it exactly as it is from the server I guess lol:  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/cifs-mount-error-5-%3D-input-output-error-but-smbfs-works-456897/

Comment: Nope, no issues with hostname as well, same issue with IP address as well, used several different "sec" options as well.

Comment: did you happen to try smbfs instead of cifs?

Answer (score 1):

The `sec=ntlm` solves it for me:

```
... -o sec=ntlm,username=...
```

Learned from:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/cifs-mount-error-5-%3D-input-output-error-but-smbfs-works-456897/#post5042181

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in kernel 3.13.0.36-generic. Check your version.

```
# kernel version    
uname -a
```

See http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg4499055.html

See [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)
for temporary solution.