# Cannot access Windows Share on Netapp from Xubuntu 14.04 using Samba

Tags: xubuntu, samba, cifs, libgcrypt

since I used to mount samba share on Netapp with a command like :

```
mount -t cifs //netapp.dns.name/myshare /home/myhome/myshare --verbose -o credential=/home/myhome/.credential,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,nounix,noserverino
```

Last week, there was OK, but monday I got this error :

```
domain=MYDOMAIN
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.nnn.nnn.nnn,unc=\\netapp.dns.name\my.login,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666,nounix,noserverino,user=olivier.savoye,,domain=MYDOMAIN,pass=********
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Here are syslog messages :

```
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959105] CPU: 2 PID: 10264 Comm: mount.cifs Tainted: G        W  OX 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959110] Hardware name: TOSHIBA PORTEGE R930/PORTEGE R930, BIOS Version 6.70   04/04/2013
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959114]  0000000000000009 ffff8801eeacfbb0 ffffffff8171e569 ffff8801eeacfbf8
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959122]  ffff8801eeacfbe8 ffffffff8106775d ffff8801eeacfd00 ffff8800a3597400
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959128]  ffff8801eeacfcc8 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 ffff8801eeacfc48
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959135] Call Trace:
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959146]  [<ffffffff8171e569>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959155]  [<ffffffff8106775d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959161]  [<ffffffff810677cc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959180]  [<ffffffffa08c04c5>] smb_send_rqst+0x215/0x270 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959191]  [<ffffffff81690218>] ? __inet_stream_connect+0x208/0x320
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959206]  [<ffffffffa08c055d>] smb_sendv+0x3d/0x40 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959218]  [<ffffffffa08c0588>] smb_send+0x28/0x30 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959232]  [<ffffffffa08aa15d>] generic_ip_connect+0x30d/0x3e0 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959243]  [<ffffffff811a1d65>] ? __kmalloc+0x55/0x230
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959258]  [<ffffffffa08ae69c>] cifs_mount+0x85c/0xaf0 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959270]  [<ffffffffa089d040>] cifs_do_mount+0xa0/0x4d0 [cifs]
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959280]  [<ffffffff811c10a9>] mount_fs+0x39/0x1b0
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959288]  [<ffffffff811dc447>] vfs_kern_mount+0x67/0x110
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959295]  [<ffffffff811deca4>] do_mount+0x244/0xb20
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959304]  [<ffffffff811530be>] ? __get_free_pages+0xe/0x50
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959310]  [<ffffffff811de8e6>] ? copy_mount_options+0x36/0x170
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959316]  [<ffffffff811df873>] SyS_mount+0x83/0xc0
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959323]  [<ffffffff8172efad>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.959327] ---[ end trace fb88cd9d7babdcb1 ]---
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.961344] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Sep 10 17:26:47 MY-BOX kernel: [27249.961529] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

There was no modification on Domain or Netapp configuration. My credential didn't change.

I looked for updates I did last week-end :

```
2014-09-05 22:37:53 upgrade libgcrypt11-dev:amd64 1.5.3-2ubuntu4 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:37:54 upgrade libgcrypt11:i386 1.5.3-2ubuntu4 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:37:55 upgrade exo-utils:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:37:55 upgrade libgcrypt11:amd64 1.5.3-2ubuntu4 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:37:56 upgrade libexo-common:all 0.10.2-3ubuntu1 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:37:57 upgrade libexo-1-0:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:37:57 upgrade libexo-helpers:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:37:58 upgrade liblua5.1-0:amd64 5.1.5-5 5.1.5-5ubuntu0.1
2014-09-05 22:37:59 upgrade ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.2.91.6 1:0.2.91.7
2014-09-05 22:38:00 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 3.13.0-35.62 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:38:02 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.22-1ubuntu1
2014-09-05 22:38:02 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.10.1-0ubuntu2
2014-09-05 22:38:02 status installed man-db:amd64 2.6.7.1-1
2014-09-05 22:38:03 status installed mime-support:all 3.54ubuntu1
2014-09-05 22:38:06 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.13-1
2014-09-05 22:38:06 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-16
2014-09-05 22:38:07 status installed libexo-common:all 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:38:07 status installed libexo-helpers:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:38:07 status installed libgcrypt11:amd64 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:38:07 status installed libgcrypt11-dev:amd64 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:38:07 status installed libgcrypt11:i386 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1
2014-09-05 22:38:08 status installed exo-utils:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:38:08 status installed libexo-1-0:amd64 0.10.2-3ubuntu1.14.04.1
2014-09-05 22:38:08 status installed liblua5.1-0:amd64 5.1.5-5ubuntu0.1
2014-09-05 22:38:09 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
2014-09-05 22:38:09 status installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:38:09 status installed ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.2.91.7
2014-09-05 22:44:29 upgrade linux-generic:amd64 3.13.0.35.42 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:44:29 upgrade linux-image-generic:amd64 3.13.0.35.42 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:44:37 upgrade linux-headers-generic:amd64 3.13.0.35.42 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:45:39 status installed linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic:amd64 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:45:52 status installed linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic:amd64 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:45:53 status installed linux-headers-3.13.0-36:all 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:45:53 status installed linux-image-generic:amd64 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:45:54 status installed linux-generic:amd64 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:45:54 status installed linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic:amd64 3.13.0-36.63
2014-09-05 22:45:54 status installed linux-headers-generic:amd64 3.13.0.36.43
2014-09-05 22:49:10 status installed libqgispython2.4.0:amd64 2.4.0+trusty1
2014-09-05 22:49:10 status installed libqscintilla2-11:amd64 2.8.1-2ubuntu1
2014-09-05 22:49:10 status installed libqscintilla2-l10n:all 2.8.1-2ubuntu1
2014-09-05 22:49:10 status installed python-psycopg2:amd64 2.4.5-1build5
2014-09-05 22:49:10 status installed python-qgis-common:all 2.4.0+trusty1
2014-09-05 22:49:11 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
2014-09-05 22:49:11 status installed python-pyspatialite:amd64 3.0.1-4
2014-09-05 22:49:11 status installed python-qgis:amd64 2.4.0+trusty1
2014-09-05 22:49:11 status installed python-qscintilla2:amd64 2.8.1-2ubuntu1
```

I don't see anything that could have an effect on my cifs mount except (perhaps) the libgcrypt11 package.

I don't try to remove it for an older because I am not sure it can help.

Could someone give me some advice ?

Comment: Does it work if you use the IP to mount it?

Comment: no, I tried it without success.

Comment: Anything changed on the NetApp box?

Comment: no, I ask my sysadmin, he confirmed

Comment: Try without `sec=ntlm` or with `ntlmv2` instead

Comment: I tried all possible options (and no option sec=) without success

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a ONTAP share.

I think it is related to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372482

Using fuse with the kernel 3.13.0-36 works OK.

Using fuse or mount.cifs with kernel 3.13.0-35 works OK.

So it seems is a 3.13.0-36 kernel problem with cifs-utils.

I have tried kernel 3.13.0-37.44 from the Canonical Kernel Team http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/canonical_kernel_team?dist=trusty without luck. Same error.

As a workaround I have changed the default kernel to 3.13.0-35 with this guide:
[Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem this week, with exaclty the same output message, as well as the one you found in syslog. I do not use a Netapp, but a simple Western Digital My Book World NAS.

In parallel I have a Synology NAS DS414 which I can mount his cifs shares without any problem.

I made some recent updates too. As part of them : the kernel; an upgrade from 3.13.0-35-generic to 3.13.0-36-generic.

**I fallback my system with the 3.13.0-35-generic kernel, and everything worked fine again.**

I still don't understand why I could mount Synology shares, and not my Western Digital ones. Except that my Western Digital used an old version of samba. Compatibility version ? Regression of the kernel ? I don't know !!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic.