# Installed new kernel, but isn't showing

Tags: kernel

I followed all the instructions found in this guide verbatim. I used the same kernel source linux 3.16 etc. I got through all the steps, rebooted, and when using uname -r, it shows my other kernel version still (3.18.3) What can I do to make the kernel the 3.16 one that I just built?

Output of update-grub:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.3
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.18.3
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When booting up, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which brings you to the grub menu.

In grub go to <kbd>Ubuntu Advanced Options</kbd> and select the kernel you want.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu. How do I get into grub when booting up?

Comment: when u start the computer u get to a grub os selector where u can select ubuntu or windows (and some other stuff such as memtest). u should get an option "advanced options for ubuntu" or something like that, select it and u should be able to select the kernel u want. but ubuntu will always select the latest kernel installed so if u want to keep using 3.16 and not 3.18 i would suggest removing 3.18

Comment: ahhh okay, This works and now I get to run my 3.16 kernel. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu loads into newest kernel by default, and 3.18 is the newest (at least , it's higher version). When you are at grub boot menu, get to `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and check if you see the 3.16 kernel there. If you do, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/216420/295286) guide for selecting the default  version to boot. Alternatively you could always find 3.18 packages with `dpkg --get-selections | grep 3.18` and the remove the relevant entries with `dpkg -r`

Small note: in the link I posted, the default entry is specified as "Previous Linux versions>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-18-generic" . You may want to change that to "Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-18-generic"

Comment: I followed the link you gave above, and I edited the GRUB_DEFAULT to be  "Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-18-generic". rebooted and still booting with the 3.18.3 kernel

Comment: 3.2.0 is the kernel number.  It was just example.  You need to put yours there , 3.16.** whatever the number is that you installed.  Better just undo the changes, remove 3.18, and then you should boot to 3.16