# Downgrade kernel 3.19.0-26-generic to 3.13.0-62-generic

Tags: kernel

I need to downgrade kernel version in my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS production server from 3.19.0-26-generic to 3.13.0-62-generic.

How I can do it in safe way ? I only have console access.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can install a specific kernel with (just change the kernel version here):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-62 linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic
```

Or use the following command to to install the latest Trusty kernel (it's 3.13.0-62 for now), not any specific version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

After that, reboot your server and hit ESC after the vendor splash screen to enter GRUB menu. Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" there, boot with the 3.13 kernel that you just installed to make sure it's working as expected.

If everything works well, you can remove the 3.19 kernel later.

Comment: I only have ssh access. I should change grub boot default to the new kernel ? Correct ?

Comment: Yes, check this article for how to change this: [Set “older” kernel as default grub entry](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: It may also be needed to install `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic`. Without this WiFi and external monitor were not working after downgrading on my laptop.