# Problem installing bbswitch on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: nvidia, kernel, bumblebee, dkms, bbswitch

I have an Nvidia Optimus graphic card installed and have the Nvidia driver installed and working for my Intel card, but I cannot switch to the Nvidia card. This is because bbswitch-dkms will not build during install via apt-get or from source.

My system

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M]
- linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic
- linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic
- linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic
- dkms: 2.2.0.3
- gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Installation command used:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-352
```

Dependency for above packages is, among others, bbswitch-dkms. When trying to install bbswitch the following error occurs:

```
Unpacking bbswitch-dkms (0.7-2ubuntu1) over (0.7-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bbswitch-dkms (0.7-2ubuntu1) ...
Loading new bbswitch-0.7 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.19.0-42-generic
Building initial module for 3.19.0-42-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/build/make.log for more information.
```

The content of make.log is:

```
DKMS make.log for bbswitch-0.7 for kernel 3.19.0-42-generic (x86_64)
lör  9 jan 2016 15:37:02 CET
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-42-generic/build M="$(pwd)" modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:114: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/build/bbswitch.o
/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/build/bbswitch.c: In function ‘is_card_disabled’:
/var/lib/dkms/bbswitch/0.7/build/bbswitch.c:236:1: internal compiler error: Bus error
 }
 ^
```

It seems this is the main problem:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:114: stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken
```

I have installed kernel-header so all building packages should be installed.

Has anyone encountered this before or know of any solutions?

Thank you!

**Update 1**

The following log entries appear in syslog during installation and building bbswitch-dkms:

```
kernel: [  235.068506] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
kernel: [  235.071273] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
kernel: [  235.074011] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
kernel: [  235.076740] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:a8:95:07/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 27 dma 4096 in
kernel: [  235.076740]          res 51/40:00:a8:95:07/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)
kernel: [  235.082207] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
kernel: [  235.084957] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
kernel: [  235.119639] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
kernel: [  235.119667] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
kernel: [  235.119674] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
kernel: [  235.119680] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
kernel: [  235.119684] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
kernel: [  235.119687] Read(10): 28 00 00 07 95 a8 00 00 08 00
kernel: [  235.119704] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497064
kernel: [  235.122090] ata1: EH complete
```

**Update 2**

Launchpad question:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bbswitch/+question/280808

Launchpad bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bbswitch/+bug/1532538

**Solved**

This is solved. See launchpad question for solution.

Comment: hmm you may try adding ppa:bumblebee/stable to your repositories, that has a more recent version of bbswitch/bumblebee: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable that may solve your problem, also make sure you have kernel headers installed!

Comment: Sorry, still get the same build error; in make.log: "stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken".

Comment: new kernel came out 3.19-0-43, you may try that one, also report that to launchpad, it is a critical bug.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the new kernel, same problem. Have reported to launchpad.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bbswitch/+bug/1532538
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bbswitch/+question/280808

Comment: i see this happen to you with other kernel modules (such as nvidia-358), right? Did bbswitch work before on older kernels? At least i can confirm it works for me on 3.19.0-30.

Comment: According to this link, make sure you have build-essentials installed http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1793162

Comment: I have not tried older kernels yet. Did a fresh install of 14.04 and did all the upgrading. It dose not matter which nvidia driver I use, bbswitch won't build correctly. I ran Debian until recently and it worked fine, don't remember which kernel version thou.

Comment: build-essentials are installed: build-essential 11.6ubuntu6

Comment: i suggest you install 3.19.0-30 use the link for instructions http://askubuntu.com/questions/668274/downgrade-kernel-3-19-0-26-generic-to-3-13-0-62-generic if this doesnt work for you, then sth is seriously messed up

Answer (score 0):

Use nvidia-prime instead of bumblebee to switch between integrated and dedicated graphics.

Uninstall all NVIDIA software and bumblebee.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers and nvidia-prime.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Open NVIDIA X Server Settings - PRIME Profiles to switch between the two graphics adapters.

Update 1 :

Alternatively install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 358 from the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Update 2 :

Maybe there is a compatibility issue or some interference with the open source nouveau drivers.
Perform the NVIDIA drivers installation from a virtual console with deactivated nouveau drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password ...
Execute the commands ...

Comment: Thank you for your respone! I have tried nvidia-primus but I get a similar error where a kernel module cannot build. I don't remember exactly which one.

Comment: @Fredrik : Which NVIDIA card do you have ?

Comment: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M]

Comment: @Fredrik : Please try the alternative from the updated answer ... important is that you remove every NVIDIA related software before ! :)

Comment: Sorry it did not work. I get the same build error as before, both for nividia-358 and bbswitch. I think this has something to do with the kernel or compilers, like gcc.

Comment: @Fredrik : Please install dkms : sudo apt-get install dkms ... and then repeat the complete procedure. :)

Comment: It's already installed at its latest version: dkms is already the newest version.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Got the same build errors.

Comment: @Fredrik : I am running out of ideas ... maybe trying another kernel version might help to solve this ... :)

Comment: I'll try that at a later point. Thank you for all of your help!