# Install another kernel?

Tags: kernel

When I give in the terminal the command "sudo apt-get install linux-image"
I see a list of kernels.
How can I install such a kernel and what command should I give in the terminal to start a kernel??

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: By default Ubuntu will boot into the latest kernel, unless you specify otherwise during boot or in /etc/default/grub file. As for installing a kernel , there's two ways: with apt or manually download a kernel from kernel.org and install. I will post a more detailed answer later , because i am on mobile. Or others my do that : there are many more qualified users than me to explain this

Comment: The answer will be different for LTS and non-LTS versions.

Comment: @Pilot6 how so ?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` on a LTS "point" version will install an older kernel, etc.

Comment: Could you please specify your reason for wanting to install a particular kernel instead of whatever kernel you already have.  As it is, I'm not convinced it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

**How can I install such a kernel?**

If you supply the package version etc it should install that version

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
```

If for some reason you want to install loads of kernel, note that if you have a `/boot` partition, or a small root one you will likely run out of disk space, so the system won't boot.

*Also, if you want to use a particular driver which only works with a certain kernel version, please make a question relevant to this*

**What command should I give in the terminal to start a kernel?**

Kernels are the base part of system, so generally you need to reboot to change what is running at the core *(probably not [with linux kernel 4+](http://www.zdnet.com/article/no-reboot-patching-comes-to-linux-4-0/) on some OSs with some updates though)*.

So change which kernel you are using you can reboot and [show GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/q/16042/178596), then you can select to use the kernel - (The nearest command is `sudo reboot` which will reboot the system). By default it will choose the latest one (usually recomended for security stuff)

**See also:**

- [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)
- [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/100953#100953)

Answer (score 0):

**Install by selecting** your choice from the list by using select/copy.  Then past your choice (using the copy/paste method to get it spelled correctly) into the apt-get install command:

Example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic 3.19.0-30.34
```

**You can choose the kernel** by clicking on `Advinced Options for Ubuntu` then move your arrow up or down for the kernel of your choice.

When you have a kernel that you are comfortable with you can edit your /boot/grub/grub.cfg (copying and pasting to ensure you have it spelled correctly) to use your preferred kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as this command works:

`sudo apt install linux-image-5.19-0-21-generic=5.19.0-21.21`

Should be "=" between name of package and version.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command in the terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-image-6.1.0-1008-oem linux-headers-6.1.0-1008-oem
```

That is for 6.1 kernel. For another kernel you have to modify the command consequently.