# Ubuntu 15.10 stopped using WiFi driver

Tags: drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 3543. To get its wifi working, I had to select "Use proprietary driver" and it used to work.

However, suddenly it has stopped using that driver. Whenever I select the driver and click on "Apply", it reverts back to "Do Not Use" and the status says "This device is not working"

I tried using a live boot CD and the WiFi works, but not on my installation. How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe a kernel update is responsible? Could you try an older kernel: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thanks but its been solved. i noticed even LAN wasn't working, found  RESET and REVERT buttons in LAN settings. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected LAN and even that wasnt working. So I went into its settings and clicked on reset and the LAN started working.

Then I tried "Use this driver" again and the stupid thing started working again. :)