# New install from cd kernel offset disabled-vfs:unable to mount root fs

Tags: boot, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a old PC with amd processor and 60 GB ssd. Ssd is unallocated now (deleted the partition using windows) and i get the message irrespective of option I choose install Ubuntu or try ubuntu or check for disk errors

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I found on my old laptop that anything newer than the 4.2.0-42 kernel will generate the same error. Maybe try an [older version of Ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)? I think 14.04 or 15.04 worked well for me. If you start with an older version and then upgrade I believe you can then later select a kernel on boot, so if one panics you can select another. (At least, I can do this from my GRUB menu selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu", and you can probably change the boot parameters to use your selected kernel persistently, but again, I'm new to this).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: You can find how to update your GRUB defaults [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry#216420).