# Booting into recovery mode remotely from the command line

Tags: 14.04, command-line, reboot, recovery-mode

I would like to reboot into the recovery mode remotely from the command line in Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

Graphically I would do:

[image]

then choose:

[image]

but I don't know how to perform this remotely through the command line interface.

Comment: You can update /etc/default/grub to choose the recovery mode option by default using the method in this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry  Not sure how to select what you want on the 2nd menu though.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to boot in recovery mode from the command line offered by GRUB?