# Ubuntu 20.04.2 freezes when coming back from suspend (due to last software update)

Tags: suspend

I have a fresh install of 20.04.2 that has been very stable for the past month, and the last software update (performed the week of 3/15/21) broke the ability for the system to come back from suspension. Now it just freezes when I try to wake from suspension, and I have to reboot it. Any idea what was in that last update that could have caused this?

Comment: Not an expert but suspend issues are closely related to hardware and therefore the kernel. First check if others are having the same issue with your particular hardware. Then consider rolling back the kernel to the version that worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/945403/how-to-downgrade-kernel-after-bad-update-16-04