# How to get rid of wrong kernel (-oracle) from Software Updater update

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, uefi, oracle

Software Updater loaded in an -oracle flavour kernel, on which no network works.
I've used Grub to set the previous, working kernel as the default.

1. How do I remove the -oracle kernel,
   1a. maybe even get the previous working kernel as a back up
   so that updater will provide only -generic kernels going forward?
   I've read [How to downgrade kernel after bad update (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945403/how-to-downgrade-kernel-after-bad-update-16-04)
   and the solution there changed to:

   sudo apt remove linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle linux-headers-5.15.0-1025-oracle

But it may or may not be the up-to-date answer for this?
I'm hesitant to try without wiser heads knowing it is a good step.

Software Updater says everything is up to date.
I've reported a bug, no action on the bug report yet.
BIOS boots to a NOT EFI, I've tried to force the EFI but it reverts no matter what I try,
one time override, disabling those entries, though I have not totally deleted those entries (2 of them are identical an not EFI)
running ZFS on the boot drive.
hwmatch error showed up after setting the default by setting

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and then updating grub.
I added the explicit `insmod hwmatch`
Which took care of that error, or at least it is not displayed on boot anymore.

(or am I completely missing something about -oracle or kernels in general? I am just a 'private' afterall.-:)

Comment: I have found this reference that explains it is connected to an issue with the nvidia drivers https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473057

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1444546/edit) to add the complete output of `sudo apt update` and the complete output of `dpkg -l | grep oracle`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on ubuntu 23.04. The issue happened yesterday with an update through update-manager. So I complete the previous output:

**sudo apt update**
Hit:1 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Φέρε:5 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_23.04 ./ InRelease [2961 B]
Hit:6 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Φέρε:7 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease [99,8 kB]

**sudo dpkg -l | grep oracle**
[sudo] password for pluto:
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1003-oracle                  6.2.0-1003.3                                amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-1003-oracle                6.2.0-1003.3                                amd64        Oracle Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1003-oracle     6.2.0-1003.3+2                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-1003 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1003-oracle      6.2.0-1003.3+2                              amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-1003-oracle

Comment: to be clear, did this do anything other than confirm the oracle kernel(s) are installed?