# Prevent installation of non-generic kernel

Tags: apt, grub2, kernel

I recently ran into the issue described at [How to get rid of wrong kernel (-oracle) from Software Updater update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444546/how-to-get-rid-of-wrong-kernel-oracle-from-software-updater-update). I fixed the issue by booting into a previously-working kernel and purging the oracle kernel.

How can I prevent this happening in the future? i.e. how do I prevent apt from installing another kernel that may break my system?

I know that it's impossible to determine whether a given kernel will break my system or not without actually trying it, but at least disallowing kernels that don't end in `-generic` seems like a good start. Is there a way to do that?