# Upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 on Samsung NC 10 80% of screen corrupted

Tags: 17.10

I have using various versions of Ubuntu over the 5 years on my Samsung NC10 netbook. This is a triple boot system which has Windows XP (the original operating system)  Windows 10 (which was an upgrade from Windows 7 ) and Ubuntu.
apart from an issue with wireless networking not starting properly a few releases ago which has since been fixed without me doing anything everything has worked as expected so I have never needed to delve into the mysteries of terminal and Linux commands.
However the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 has not worked as on booting up the system and selecting the Ubuntu option the  screen eventually stabilises with about 80% on the left hand side corrupted and the remaining 20% written correctly. I can select the drop down menu for shut down but  the pop up menu is obviously displayed in the corrupted bit. So I have to do a hard reset.

Tips please on what to do next.

Answer (score 3):

The same issue happens on Acer Aspire One A110 (ZG5)

- When system is booting and grub shows up, press "e"
- Find line with "ro quiet splash" and add nomodeset so it says "ro nomodeset quiet splash".
- Press CTRL-X to continue booting

Then there are two workarounds:

1. if you need the new kernel 4.13, you can add "`nomodeset`" to your kernel options permanently, but this will limit screen resolution to 800x600:

   - `$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
   - Then add "`nomodeset`" as below:
   - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`
   - `$ sudo update-grub`
2. if you don't mind running older kernel 4.10 and want full 1024x600 resolution, try this solution [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry) to set up kernel 4.10 as default (framebuffer works fine in this version, in 1024x600 and without having to use nomodeset)

Comment: Thanks for this, as you suggest the framebuffer works fine with kernel 4.10. What is the way forward? will the problem with 4. 13 be fixed at some point or is there an edit of 4.13 that will give 1024 x 600?

Comment: That's question to Ubuntu developers. If the bug isn't here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/ we should report it. I'll try to do it later today, but feel free to report it yourself if you can do it right now :-)

Comment: I have reported this bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1728022

Answer (score 0):

I have just observed the same problem. I was able to boot into the previous kernel (4.10.0-37) successfully. Also, booting into recovery mode in the latest kernel (4.13.0-16) and immediately selecting 'continue' boots successfully into an 800 by 600 screen. Not a solution but at least you can use the netbook.

Comment: Please consider expanding this answer to be more specific about the steps that are needed to accomplish the fix.  Perhaps a small step by step list would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this issue on my Samsung N130 using 17.10.1 (artful) was slightly different. The suggested lines in the normal grub weren't there. The fault was in the graphics driver trying to set an invalid resolution, or one that the video card really doesn't like.

To get around it the correct way is to force grub to use "terminal" mode.

- Edit `/etc/defult/grub` using your favourite command-line editor (vi, nano, whatever) in recovery mode or through SSH (if enabled).
- Look for the line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` and remove the `#`
- Save and exit your editor
- Run `update-grub2`
- Reboot

Grub should be in the default boot VGA resolution, but Linux should still boot up using the native resolution of your display and work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround helps to get working the display normaly:

Suspend the system in the corrupted login screen (luckily the 20% good screen shows the dropup menu to choose)
Wake up the system (press power button)
and the login screen is showing up normaly