# How does one use GRUB_DEFAULT to select a default OS for boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I am running UBUNTU 17.10 and have more than one Linux kernel that I might want to run.

According to the [current grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html), GRUB_DEFAULT is "the default menu entry. This may be a number, in which case it identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero, or the title of a menu entry, or the special string ‘saved’. Using the id may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default even though there may be a variable number of entries before it."

The grub menu no longer gives the various OS options. It provides a menu element named Advanced. Selecting this menu item brings up a submenu of bootable kernels. GRUB_DEFAULT does not index this submenu.

Should I add my own custom boot options to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and reference these menu items in the grub.menu? This solution seems cumbersome. Defining a default kernel was much simpler in the past.

Comment: Are you asking for default kernel or OS? See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: I am only using the Linux OS but about 7 different versions (kernels) thereof.

Comment: yes i need to also know this so i can reboot HEADLESS into another os without using any cursoring around interactively. otherwise, save default is good but man grub sucks turds.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the easiest way to do this...

Edit `/etc/default/grub`...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

near the top of the file, edit/add these parameters...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then update grub...

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you boot, it'll remember the last OS you selected, and make that the default until the next time that you choose a different OS.

Comment: I share the machine with two other users that boot other versions of Linux. I would prefer that the default version of Linux be the same for all of us. It's a vanilla version of Linux on which none of us is hacking.

All of us at various times boot other than the default version of Linux.

Comment: I put the following GRUB_DEFAULT directive in /etc/default/grub.
`GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"`

-------
After I executed update-grub and rebooted, the system booted the 3rd kernel in the Advanced submenu. I found this procedure in another askubuntu answer. I have yet to find a passage in the [grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/) that discusses this usage of GRUB_DEFAULT.

Comment: I found where in the manual navigating submenus with GRUB_DEFAULT is almost discussed: [15.1.10 default](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/default.html#default).

Comment: @JoachimMartillo: It may be a few years late, but I found the `>` construct described at https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/default.html