# Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, updates

Today I got what I presume was the update that should take care of Spectre and Meltdown. That didn't go very well. What do I do now?
See screen photo.

[image]

I can't boot the 4.4.0-108-generic kernel because of a kernel panic. I'm running 16.04 on an Intel Core i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4.

Comment: This bug related to the kernel update for the famous Meltdown CPU vulnerability (I don't know why people have edited-out that from the title of the question): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742323

Comment: I had the same issue.
14.04 updated to Meltdown patch. I set previous kernel *.104 in GRUB and Ubuntu started ok.

Comment: **Kernel 4.4.0-109 has been released. Please update your systems.**

Comment: My saviour [https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: 4.4.0-109 is still broken for my Ubuntu 16.04 host running under VirtualBox.

Comment: Yes, there is an image of a black screen in this question, but no this question is not a duplicate of a generic black screen question because this question is about a **specific situation** that has a **specific answer**.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Do not install 4.4.0-108-generic on Xenial! It [breaks boot/reboot/shutdown/suspend functionality](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1741934)!

## Install 4.4.0-109-generic ([see USN-3522-3](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3522-3/) for details)!

---

Reboot to the last working kernel and remove 4.4.0-108-generic:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> between UEFI/BIOS and login-screen to enter GRUB
2. In GRUB select `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and select `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-xxx-generic` (where `xxx` < 108)
3. Login to the system and remove this buggy 4.4.0-108-generic and install 4.4.0-104-generic instead.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-108 linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic \
   linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic \
   linux-tools-4.4.0-108 linux-tools-4.4.0-108-generic
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic \
   linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic \
   linux-tools-4.4.0-104 linux-tools-4.4.0-104-generic
   ```

As of 2018-01-10 18:00 UTC, the 4.4.0-109-generic kernel seems to be distributed on mirrors.

But if you want you can select **Main server** (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu).
You can switch to it from `software-properties-gtk` / `software-properties-kde`.

You can install 4.4.0-109-generic with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic \
linux-headers-generic linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic \
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-generic \
linux-tools-4.4.0-109 linux-tools-4.4.0-109-generic linux-tools-generic
```

Comment: When I run `autoremove` after purging the `4.4.0-108` it asks me to remove the `4.4.0-103` versions - is that what I want to do?

Comment: You can skip autoremove if this your only one kernel. Previous working was 104.

Comment: I had updates turned off after I read Mesa broke other peoples' systems on Jan 4, 2018; so never got `108`. `109` appears to be there already though: `linux-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security 4.4.0.109.114 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.104.109]`

Comment: @N0rbert How to install 4.4.0.109-generic? What are the command lines?

Comment: @Graham I updated my post.

Comment: Your instructions are to override boot and select `4.4.0-104`--all good. Then purge version `4.4.0-108` that suffers a meltdown over meltdown fix--all good. Then install `4.4.0-104` but you just booted with it so why would you install it? What am I missing...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix this is for safety reasons. 108 and maybe 109 have side-effects, 104 does not. 104 is last known-good kernel, it should in the system on next `purge-old-kernels` or `auto-remove`. And current running may be not 104.

Comment: @N0rbert Understood. If current running isn't 104 then instruction for step #2 should be fine-tuned. Now it says "in GRUB select Advanced options for Ubuntu and select Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-104-generic". Something like "previous version to 108" would make more sense. Sorry if it's nit-picking.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done, thank you!

Comment: I just got an update for 4.4.0-109-generic and I am unable to login from the UI. I can login to the terminal. Does anything special have to be done after this upgrade? For now, I have reverted to 104.

Comment: 4.4.0-109 is still broken for my Ubuntu 16.04 host running under VirtualBox.

Comment: The same thing happened to me couple of days ago. Followed the instruction here and it worked. However, today the 4.4.0-109 crashed, and even go back to 104 doesn't help. I have to manually fsck and have it fixed. Now I can login using 104. I probably will stick with 104 for now.

Answer (score 6):

In your boot menu choose `advanced options for ubuntu`.

You can boot from an older kernel (that is still installed) there.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me:

1. Using grub boot menu, boot older kernel version.
2. Install even newer kernel

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`

update:
looks like issue with version 4.4.0.108
fixed with version 4.4.0.109 released just now.

Comment: Many users do not need 4.13. It will be supported until [middle of 2018](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Answer (score -1):

You can install the latest patch successfully if you boot with an older kernel (I went back about three releases) then run Ubuntu's all of Ubuntu's advanced options "system cleaning" tools including fsck.  There apparently is something in the earlier releases that must be "fixed" before the patch can be installed successfully.