# Booting problem black screen

Tags: boot

When I boot Ubuntu 16.04 it is booting to a black screen. The below image contains the error message.

[image]

Comment: Try booting an old kernel.

Comment: This looks more like a kernel problem than a graphics driver problem.

Comment: This is another duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-1-10-2018-update-to-16-04 being mis marked as https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it