# How to update Ubuntu 16.04 to include meltdown and spectre patch

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, security

I have tried upgrading 2 separate Ubuntu systems to include the latest meltdown patch to no avail.

Here is what I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ reboot 
$ uname -r
4.4.0-42-generic
```

This article https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3522-1/ seems to suggest that there is a solution for 16.04 and the way to install it is to use the instructions above.

What am I missing?

**EDIT1:**

After running successfully

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

the kernel is still the same

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-42-generic
```

so I ran the following as per David's request

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-image-generic 'linux-image-4\.4\.0-.*-generic'
linux-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0.108.113
  Candidate: 4.4.0.108.113
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0.108.113 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0.108.113
  Candidate: 4.4.0.108.113
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0.108.113 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-92.115
  Version table:
     4.4.0-92.115 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-38.57
  Version table:
     4.4.0-38.57 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-75.96
  Version table:
     4.4.0-75.96 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-36.55
  Version table:
     4.4.0-36.55 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-57.78
  Version table:
     4.4.0-57.78 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-78.99
  Version table:
     4.4.0-78.99 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-77.98
  Version table:
     4.4.0-77.98 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-97.120
  Version table:
     4.4.0-97.120 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-21.37
  Version table:
     4.4.0-21.37 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-59.80
  Version table:
     4.4.0-59.80 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-101.124
  Version table:
     4.4.0-101.124 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-96.119
  Version table:
     4.4.0-96.119 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-79.100
  Version table:
     4.4.0-79.100 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-104.127
  Version table:
     4.4.0-104.127 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-81.104
  Version table:
     4.4.0-81.104 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-103.126
  Version table:
     4.4.0-103.126 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-98.121
  Version table:
     4.4.0-98.121 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-22.40
  Version table:
     4.4.0-22.40 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-43.63
  Version table:
     4.4.0-43.63 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-42.62
  Version table:
     4.4.0-42.62 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-63.84
  Version table:
     4.4.0-63.84 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-62.83
  Version table:
     4.4.0-62.83 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-83.106
  Version table:
     4.4.0-83.106 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-24.43
  Version table:
     4.4.0-24.43 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-45.66
  Version table:
     4.4.0-45.66 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-28.47
  Version table:
     4.4.0-28.47 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0-108.131
  Candidate: 4.4.0-108.131
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0-108.131 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-64.85
  Version table:
     4.4.0-64.85 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-47.68
  Version table:
     4.4.0-47.68 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-67.88
  Version table:
     4.4.0-67.88 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-66.87
  Version table:
     4.4.0-66.87 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-87.110
  Version table:
     4.4.0-87.110 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-31.50
  Version table:
     4.4.0-31.50 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-51.72
  Version table:
     4.4.0-51.72 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-89.112
  Version table:
     4.4.0-89.112 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-71.92
  Version table:
     4.4.0-71.92 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-70.91
  Version table:
     4.4.0-70.91 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-91.114
  Version table:
     4.4.0-91.114 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-53.74
  Version table:
     4.4.0-53.74 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-72.93
  Version table:
     4.4.0-72.93 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-93.116
  Version table:
     4.4.0-93.116 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.0-34.53
  Version table:
     4.4.0-34.53 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Ubuntu's status on the Meltdown and Spectre vulnerabilities?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992232/what-is-ubuntus-status-on-the-meltdown-and-spectre-vulnerabilities)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic) The latest kernel patch in 4.4.0-109-generic has already been released on some update servers. This update might take another day or two until it arrives at all update servers.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-image-generic 'linux-image-4\.4\.0-.*-generic'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now that a good patch for your kernel is available, do

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

This should force the kernel upgrade for you.

Comment: still get same kernel as before even after completing this command and rebooting !!!

Comment: @GiorgosK Please check David's comment on your original question