# virtualbox crash on kernel 4.13.0-26

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Virtualbox 5.0.40 ubuntu r 115130

Today after upgrading to kernel 4.13.0-26 guest vbox machines started to crash whole ubuntu. just hard poweroff is working.

If I startup with kernel 4.10.0-42 everything works fine.

what may be the problem ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-1-10-2018-update-to-16-04

Comment: Ubuntu was patched on 1/9/2018 to fix the Meltdown Security hole. Apparently the patch was rushed out and it caused a kernel panic (system crash). It was fixed the next day 1/10/2018 and all reports are things are ok. You can boot with grub and select `Advanced Options` then pick older kernel version. You can run `sudo apt upgrade` from the terminal and get the latest kernel which should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I did boot with older kernel, run "sudo apt upgrade". It outputs "0 packages to upgrade". I have updated repo address to main servers, still same.

Comment: I also tried "sudo apt upgrade" and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Virtualbox 5.0.40 is not working with the new kernel (4.13.0-26), but the new version of VBox (5.2) works fine.

Download it from VirtualBox page or add the source to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

If you use a different version of Ubuntu than 16.04, use the appropriate name instead of **xenial**.

Add Oracle public key:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update repositories and install `virtualbox-5.2`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
```

On one of my laptops, VM didn't want to start before I removed virutalbox-dkms:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
```

After the update, I had a problem after starting the virtual-machine (see [VirtualBox - RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900794/virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed-with-rc-1912-rc-1912)). As suggested in the first comment, it had been fixed with the following call:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Comment: I think it is `/etc/apt/sources.list` instead of `/etc/sources.list`

Comment: You are right. I corrected in the original  answer.

Comment: as a note, I had a existing virtual machine with USB support enabled, I had to disable it in order to get the VM started, the Guest Additions package seems to be incompatible.

Answer (score 5):

There is already a bug report on launchpad.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1736116

It is our best shot to get this bug fixed.

Temporary, we can

- boot the old kernel 4.10.0-42 from the grub menu (not recommended)
- boot the latest 4.4 LTS kernel from the grub menu, which is still getting security patches

  If it is not already installed:
  `sudo apt install linux-generic`

or

- upgrade virtualbox from the oracle sources