# Virtualbox freezing on start up 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, oracle

When I boot my Virtual Machine in Oracle Virtualbox it freezes. I am unable to move the mouse, audio begins looping.

I will include my system log to see if anyone can make sense of this. Even pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

(literally was working yesterday. and now absolutely nothing.)

```
Jan 11 09:00:40 thispc org.debian.apt[851]: 09:00:40 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Updating cache
Jan 11 09:00:47 thispc AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/7241eeffd78442b199b06c20d1071535
Jan 11 09:00:47 thispc org.debian.apt[851]: 09:00:47 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/7241eeffd78442b199b06c20d1071535
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 108...
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1088]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 3387 (kill).
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Jan 11 09:01:23 thispc systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="868" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc systemd-modules-load[259]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc systemd-modules-load[259]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc systemd-modules-load[259]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc loadkeys[258]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Jan 11 09:03:37 thispc systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
```

Comment: Various others have mentioned that VM is not working after the update - There is some indication that downloading and running the current version of VB from Oracle does work.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand why, but I rebooted with the 4.10 kernel instead of the 4.13 and it fixed the issue.

I think the issue is with the latest Kernel update.

Comment: The problem with remaining on the 4.10 kernel, is that the 4.13 kernel contains the fix for the [Meltdown bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown) - you could regress to the 4.4 kernel, which also contains the patch.

Comment: I tried following the Oracle official tutorial on a re-install with the new kernel. (I am a bit concerned about the security of reverting.) 

This is the message I'm receiving when I try to use the VM I imported from the repository virtual box.


RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

Comment: Please see [https://askubuntu.com/a/994653/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/994653/283721)