# I get an error when creating a VM on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I'm trying to create a Rancher server but I get the following error:

```
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm rancher-server --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'rancher-server' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I'm using VirtualBox 5.2 and I've also tried with version 5.1 getting the same result. I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed in my laptop.

Error message:
[image: Screenshot with error message]

Comment: What does `uname -r` reveal in the terminal?

Comment: 4.10.0-40-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 days ago someone reported getting [this error](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8687) after upgrading Virtual Box from version 5.1 to 5.2. Their solution below:

I got this error after upgrading from Virtualbox 5.1 to 5.2, as installed on Ubuntu from the Virtualbox PPA. I solved it by purging config files for 5.1 as well as uninstalling virtualbox-dkms 5.1:

```
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox-5.1
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox-dkms
```

---

As you are running Kernel 4.10.0-xx you may be interested in this if you upgrade some day: [virtualbox crash on kernel 4.13.0-26](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994315/virtualbox-crash-on-kernel-4-13-0-26)