# login loop after upgrading to 4.4.0-116 kernel: graphical login screen -> black screen -> graphical login screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, upgrade, kernel, graphics

Can't login into desktop environment after `apt upgrade && reboot`: on entering password the screen flickers into a black screen and returns back to the login screen. Login via the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>) works fine.

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says:

> (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
>   (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
>   (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
>   (EE) No devices detected.

`$ dmesg` says:

> nvidia: version magic '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline '

Trying to load the nvidia driver manually fails:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Exec format error
```

Related: [VirtualBox not starting after kernel upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/1008681/3712)

Comment: @Jeremy it is a different issue. Read the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with gcc version that doesn't support retpoline ([What is a retpoline and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48089426/4279)). See Ubuntu bug: [4.4.0-116 Kernel update on 2/21 breaks Nvidia drivers (on 14.04 and 16.04)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1750937).

In my case, purging `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` to install the default gcc version and rebuilding with DKMS the nvidia module (by reinstalling 4.4.0-116 kernel) fixes the problem. See [instructions posted by @cjjefcoat on the bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1750937/comments/57).

Restore default gcc by purging `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`'s version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

gcc version (on Ubuntu 16.04) with retpoline support:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Reinstall kernel:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic
$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-signed-generic
```

Check nvidia module:

```
$ modinfo nvidia_xxx -k 4.4.0-116-generic | grep vermagic
vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline
```

<sup>replace `_xxx` with your version -- just press TAB after `modinfo nvidia`</sup>

`retpoline` should be in the output.

After that `reboot` completed successfully.

---

If you have compatible gcc version already, you could rebuild nvidia module using `dkms` command without reinstalling the kernel:

```
# dkms remove nvidia-xxx/yyy.zzz -k 4.4.0-116-generic
# dkms install nvidia-xxx/yyy.zzz -k 4.4.0-116-generic
```

I've decided to reinstall the kernel instead to update all modules that were re-built with DKMS using a wrong gcc version.

Comment: I am sure I have the same problem but I don't have "ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test" It seems my default version of gcc is Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04. Any advice?

Comment: @OleksiiRudenko /usr/bin/gcc points to gcc-5 on my machine (16.04). `apt policy gcc-5` shows 5.4.0-... (not 5.4.1) from expected repositories.

Comment: I have figured it out. So I have already had the ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test removed. So in order to purge packages, I had to add it first `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`.  The rest of steps worked as expected plus I had to reinstall nvidia driver:  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-384`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether Ask Ubuntu is a correct place for that shit, but — as I **need** new `g++` and still periodically update kernel — I've written a bash-script that (1) purges `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`, (2) rebuilds all DKMS-modules for chosen kernels, (3) installs `g++-7` back — per [this answer](//askubuntu.com/a/1009726).

The script is provided "as is", without warranties of any kind.
**Please, don't use it unless you understand the meaning of every line.**
It's intended for saving time when doing things you are able to do manually (not for doing "magic" you don't understand).

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

for list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r*.list; do
    sudo cp -a "$list" "$list.backup"
    echo "Backed up $list to $list.backup"
done
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

readarray -t kernels < <(ls -1 /lib/modules)
echo "Kernels: ${kernels[*]}"
for kernel in "${kernels[@]}"; do
    dkms_modules=($(sudo dkms status -k "$kernel" | sed -r 's#^([^,]+), ([^,]+), .*$#\1/\2#'))
    while true; do
        echo
        read -p "Reinstall DKMS-modules (${dkms_modules[*]}) on kernel $kernel? [Y/n] " choice
        if [ "${choice^^}" = N ]; then continue 2; fi
        if [ "${choice^^}" = Y ] || [ -z "$choice" ]; then break; fi
        echo "Expected 'y', 'n' or '', but got '$choice'"
    done
    echo
    for dkms_module in "${dkms_modules[@]}"; do
        sudo dkms remove -k "$kernel" "$dkms_module"
        sudo dkms install -k "$kernel" "$dkms_module"
    done
    echo
    for module in /lib/modules/"$kernel"/updates/dkms/*.ko; do
        vermagic="$(modinfo -F vermagic $module)"
        echo -n "Vermagic for $(basename ${module%.ko}): $vermagic -- "
        fgrep -q retpoline <<<"$vermagic" && echo ok || echo "'retpoline' is missing!!!"
    done
done

for list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r*.list; do
    sudo mv "$list.backup" "$list"
    echo "Restored $list from $list.backup"
done
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++-7
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```