# Errors were encountered while processing: Linux-headers-4.4.0-116

Tags: kernel, linux-headers, ros

[image]

[Trying to install Ros kinetic but keeping getting this error, I upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 through the command line and broke something in the process. Terminal keeps telling me I have broken packages. I used to have two errors that said:

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-116
Linux-headers-4.4.0-116 generic
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009725/login-loop-after-upgrading-to-4-4-0-116-kernel-graphical-login-screen-black) and it fixed the error for `linux-headers-4.4.0-116 generic`

But now I can't fix this:

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-116
```

ran `uname -r` to see what kernel I'm running it was:

```
4.4.0-117
```

but than I tried installing a different kernel and it installed

```
4.13.0-37-generic
```

current `uname-r` is:

```
4.13.0-37-generic
```

Looked around online and couldn't find a clear answer on this problem. Not sure if I should just install Linux 16.04 altogether or if there is an easy fix for this problem?