# Ubuntu VirtualBox error

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

My question is a duplicate of [VirtualBox not starting after kernel upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008681/virtualbox-not-starting-after-kernel-upgrade?newreg=7661c0ea432249ee9527821ae1881c07). My system configuration is as shown below.

```
reclusiarch@reclusiarch-Inspiron-7520:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
reclusiarch@reclusiarch-Inspiron-7520:~$ uname -a
Linux reclusiarch-Inspiron-7520 4.4.0-116-generic #140~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 09:25:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had already purged the repository ( https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) before discovering that I could not install gcc-5 without the said respository for Ubuntu 14.04. My question are as follows:
 **Is there a way to revert my virtualbox installation back to a working installation and if so, how I proceed?** Thanks for not closing this question.

Comment: That's right, gcc 5.4.0 is not packaged for Ubuntu 14.04. There is no supported solution within the constraints you have provided (won't upgrade to 16.04)

Comment: @user535733 So I have downgraded to gcc-4.9. How do I proceed?

Comment: How do you proceed with what? Your question is not clear about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user53733 I fixed my question. I am sorry if I came off as unwilling before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 14.04 and use virtualbox.

On my system, `gcc-version` returns

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
```

It comes from trusty-updates repository as shown here

```
gcc-4.8:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

After confirming that you have this version of the compiler, you need to remove and reinstall the latest kernel version using these commands (culled from the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1750937))

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic

sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-signed-generic
```

and reboot into the new kernel.

Finally you need to rebuild the vbox kernel driver now that you have the right kernel and right compiler

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

There may be other compiler versions that work, but this one is proven to work.

Comment: How do i switch back to gcc-4.8? My system automatically installed it but when I run `gcc--version`, it tells me that it cant find it?

Comment: Look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version Ale's answer may be best.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the link. After rebooting, I tried  running the command `sudo apt-get linux-generic linux-signed-generic`.It asks to install linux-image-3.13.0-142, is that normal/ok?

Comment: On my system the kernel before virtualbox broke was 4.4.0-112 and installing the -116 caused the problem. If you didn't do the hwe update to 14.04 your system may be using a different set of kernels. Or there may be some other difference between our systems. what virtual packages were removed when you removed the -116 kernel-just reinstall them.

Comment: I ran the `hwe-support-status` so it said that my system was supported till April 2019. Should I then go ahead and run the `sudo apt-get linux-generic linux-signed-generic` command or skip it and rebuild vbox kernel? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it will hurt to try that, it should rebuild it for the running kernel.