# What's wrong with my Lubuntu desktop (not loading)?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm

After recently updating my Lubuntu install (on an old (>10 years) netbook), the desktop no longer loads. After showing the standard terminal checks, the taskbar will usually load, but the rest of the desktop won't. THe taskbar will update as well. For example, if I turn off wifi, the taskbar will show I am no longer connected. If I quit dropbox, the taskbar removes that icon. I can still use the computer in the terminal with ctrl+alt+F1, etc., but the desktop won't load.

Any ideas how I can fix this, what to look for, etc.? I'd like to avoid a reinstall if possible, mostly because I'd prefer to learn something since this isn't my main machine. Also, if the update broke something, a reinstall won't help much.

[image: Desktop]
Usually the taskbar loads correctly (with "start" menu, status icons, etc.). It stopped doing so after a little troubleshooting.

Edit: Lubuntu 16.04, Intel Atom N270.

Most recent update:

```
Start-Date: 2018-02-21  14:49:08
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: user (1000)
Upgrade: ca-certificates-java:i386 (20160321, 20160321ubuntu1), evince:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2, 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.3), libnm-glib4:i386 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), libmpx0:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), lubuntu-core:i386 (0.65.2, 0.65.3), libdns-export162:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), python2.7-dev:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), libgcc-5-dev:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), poppler-utils:i386 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6), libgles2-mesa:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libseccomp2:i386 (2.2.3-3ubuntu3, 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1), libaudit-common:i386 (1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2, 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1), libisccfg140:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), libcups2:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), intel-microcode:i386 (3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0, 3.20180108.0+really20170707ubuntu16.04.1), update-manager-core:i386 (1:16.04.10, 1:16.04.12), uuid-runtime:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), unity-control-center-faces:i386 (15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu1, 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1), libfdisk1:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), transmission-common:i386 (2.84-3ubuntu3, 2.84-3ubuntu3.1), linux-libc-dev:i386 (4.4.0-101.124, 4.4.0-116.140), libevdocument3-4:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2, 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.3), libcurl3:i386 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6), libapt-inst2.0:i386 (1.2.24, 1.2.25), openssl:i386 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.9, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libc6-dev:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), update-notifier-common:i386 (3.168.5, 3.168.7), libwbclient0:i386 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.11, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12), libgweather-3-6:i386 (3.18.2-0ubuntu0.1, 3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2), libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libpulsedsp:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), grub-common:i386 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), apt:i386 (1.2.24, 1.2.25), libparted2:i386 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), pulseaudio:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), cpp-5:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libglapi-mesa:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), python2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), libmount1:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), update-manager:i386 (1:16.04.10, 1:16.04.12), binutils:i386 (2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.5, 2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.6), bind9-host:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04:i386 (1.3.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1, 1.4.0-1~16.04.1), libitm1:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libpython-all-dev:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), dnsutils:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), libunity-protocol-private0:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, 7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), libpython2.7:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), python2.7:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), dnsmasq-base:i386 (2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.4), libc6:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), libxcursor1:i386 (1:1.1.14-1, 1:1.1.14-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-unity-5.0:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, 7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), util-linux:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), libnuma1:i386 (2.0.11-1ubuntu1, 2.0.11-1ubuntu1.1), libpython3.5:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), python3.5:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), python3.5-minimal:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), grub2-common:i386 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), libisc160:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), libvorbisfile3:i386 (1.3.5-3, 1.3.5-3ubuntu0.1), libpython2.7-dev:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), udev:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libcilkrts5:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), locales:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), cups-server-common:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), libnm0:i386 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), resolvconf:i386 (1.78ubuntu5, 1.78ubuntu6), libasan2:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libquadmath0:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), transmission:i386 (2.84-3ubuntu3, 2.84-3ubuntu3.1), libklibc:i386 (2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.3, 2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.4), python3.5-dev:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), cups-common:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), network-manager:i386 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), libapt-pkg5.0:i386 (1.2.24, 1.2.25), libwavpack1:i386 (4.75.2-2, 4.75.2-2ubuntu0.1), python:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), initramfs-tools-bin:i386 (0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), grub-pc:i386 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), libminiupnpc10:i386 (1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2.16.04.1, 1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2.16.04.2), libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libapparmor1:i386 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), unity-control-center:i386 (15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu1, 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1), gnome-disk-utility:i386 (3.18.3.1-1ubuntu1, 3.18.3.1-1ubuntu1.1), mount:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), libnm-util2:i386 (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), samba-libs:i386 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.11, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12), grub-pc-bin:i386 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), gcc-5-base:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), apport:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libpython-stdlib:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), libblkid1:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), dpkg:i386 (1.18.4ubuntu1.2, 1.18.4ubuntu1.3), evince-common:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2, 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.3), libstdc++-5-dev:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libapparmor-perl:i386 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), libisc-export160:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), libc-bin:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), libubsan0:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libpulse0:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), cups-ppdc:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), g++-5:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), python3-update-manager:i386 (1:16.04.10, 1:16.04.12), libcupsmime1:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), libevview3-3:i386 (3.18.2-1ubuntu4.2, 3.18.2-1ubuntu4.3), python3-apport:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libpython-dev:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), libvorbisenc2:i386 (1.3.5-3, 1.3.5-3ubuntu0.1), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), systemd-sysv:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libuuid1:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), gcc-5:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), liblwres141:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), libunity9:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, 7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), python-all:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), libpam-systemd:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libxfont1:i386 (1:1.5.1-1ubuntu0.16.04.3, 1:1.5.1-1ubuntu0.16.04.4), libxfont2:i386 (1:2.0.1-3~ubuntu16.04.2, 1:2.0.1-3~ubuntu16.04.3), distro-info-data:i386 (0.28ubuntu0.5, 0.28ubuntu0.7), parted:i386 (3.2-15, 3.2-15ubuntu0.1), systemd:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libgomp1:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libpython3.5-dev:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:i386 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libsmartcols1:i386 (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), libmbim-proxy:i386 (1.12.2-2ubuntu1, 1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), python-dev:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), apt-utils:i386 (1.2.24, 1.2.25), iproute2:i386 (4.3.0-1ubuntu3.16.04.2, 4.3.0-1ubuntu3.16.04.3), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:i386 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.3, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.4), libsmbclient:i386 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.11, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12), openssh-client:i386 (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2, 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4), libdb5.3:i386 (5.3.28-11, 5.3.28-11ubuntu0.1), bsdutils:i386 (1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3, 1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4), libdns162:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:i386 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4, 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1), pulseaudio-module-x11:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), apport-gtk:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), libunity-control-center1:i386 (15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu1, 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1), libc-dev-bin:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), libxml2:i386 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.3, 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.5), libcupsppdc1:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:i386 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libpython2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), multiarch-support:i386 (2.23-0ubuntu9, 2.23-0ubuntu10), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), transmission-gtk:i386 (2.84-3ubuntu3, 2.84-3ubuntu3.1), firefox:i386 (57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5, 58.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), rsync:i386 (3.1.1-3ubuntu1, 3.1.1-3ubuntu1.2), apparmor:i386 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7, 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8), libisccc140:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), apt-transport-https:i386 (1.2.24, 1.2.25), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04:i386 (1:1.0.14-0ubuntu1~16.04.1, 1:1.0.15-2~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04:i386 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4, 2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1), libpython3.5-stdlib:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), cups-core-drivers:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), linux-firmware:i386 (1.157.13, 1.157.16), libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:i386 (7.1.4+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1, 7.1.4+16.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu1), libatomic1:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), libvorbis0a:i386 (1.3.5-3, 1.3.5-3ubuntu0.1), libbind9-140:i386 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10), cups-daemon:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), libtasn1-6:i386 (4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.2, 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.3), libcc1-0:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04:i386 (1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1, 1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1), libcupsimage2:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3), libpoppler-glib8:i386 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6), libpython3.5-minimal:i386 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4), libpoppler58:i386 (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.5, 0.41.0-0ubuntu1.6), libstdc++6:i386 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), cups:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), pulseaudio-utils:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7), curl:i386 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6), libdpkg-perl:i386 (1.18.4ubuntu1.2, 1.18.4ubuntu1.3), libcupscgi1:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), cups-client:i386 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:i386 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), klibc-utils:i386 (2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.3, 2.0.4-8ubuntu1.16.04.4), libmbim-glib4:i386 (1.12.2-2ubuntu1, 1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), update-notifier:i386 (3.168.5, 3.168.7), python3-problem-report:i386 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.12, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15), ubuntu-mono:i386 (14.04+16.04.20161024-0ubuntu1, 14.04+16.04.20171116-0ubuntu1), python-minimal:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04), libgweather-common:i386 (3.18.2-0ubuntu0.1, 3.18.2-0ubuntu0.2), libaudit1:i386 (1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2, 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1), initramfs-tools-core:i386 (0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.6), initramfs-tools:i386 (0.122ubuntu8.9, 0.122ubuntu8.10), xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:i386 (1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1, 1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:i386 (2.18.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.18.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.9, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10), dpkg-dev:i386 (1.18.4ubuntu1.2, 1.18.4ubuntu1.3), python-all-dev:i386 (2.7.11-1, 2.7.12-1~16.04)
End-Date: 2018-02-21  15:06:39

Start-Date: 2018-02-22  00:45:57
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Requested-By: user (1000)
Install: linux-headers-4.4.0-116:i386 (4.4.0-116.140, automatic), libatkmm-1.6-1v5:i386 (2.24.2-1, automatic), libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 (2.6.2-1, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic:i386 (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1, automatic), libqmi-glib5:i386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic:i386 (4.4.0-116.140, automatic), linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic:i386 (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1, automatic), libllvm5.0:i386 (1:5.0-3~16.04.1, automatic), pavucontrol:i386 (3.0-3build1, automatic), linux-headers-4.13.0-36:i386 (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic:i386 (4.4.0-116.140, automatic), libcairomm-1.0-1v5:i386 (1.12.0-1, automatic), libglibmm-2.4-1v5:i386 (2.46.3-1, automatic), libpangomm-1.4-1v5:i386 (2.38.1-1, automatic), linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic:i386 (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic:i386 (4.4.0-116.140, automatic), libdrm-common:i386 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, automatic), libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:i386 (3.18.0-1, automatic)
Upgrade: libqmi-proxy:i386 (1.12.6-1, 1.16.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-headers-generic:i386 (4.4.0.101.106, 4.4.0.116.122), linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:i386 (4.10.0.40.42, 4.13.0.36.55), linux-image-generic:i386 (4.4.0.101.106, 4.4.0.116.122), linux-generic-hwe-16.04:i386 (4.10.0.40.42, 4.13.0.36.55), libxatracker2:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libegl1-mesa:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), lubuntu-desktop:i386 (0.65.2, 0.65.3), libgbm1:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libmm-glib0:i386 (1.4.12-1ubuntu1, 1.6.4-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1, 2.4.83-1~16.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), modemmanager:i386 (1.4.12-1ubuntu1, 1.6.4-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04:i386 (4.10.0.40.42, 4.13.0.36.55), linux-generic:i386 (4.4.0.101.106, 4.4.0.116.122)
End-Date: 2018-02-22  00:55:23

Start-Date: 2018-02-22  00:55:48
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: user (1000)
Remove: linux-headers-4.4.0-101:i386 (4.4.0-101.124), linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic:i386 (4.4.0-101.124), linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic:i386 (4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1), libllvm4.0:i386 (1:4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.2), linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic:i386 (4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic:i386 (4.4.0-101.124), linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic:i386 (4.4.0-101.124), linux-headers-4.10.0-37:i386 (4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1), linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic:i386 (4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-02-22  00:58:05
```

Additionally, this message has been popping up occasionally:
[image: Error message.]
I'm not sure if it's related at all.

If there's any other information that would be helpful, let me know.

Comment: What version are you using (16.04, 18.04, etc)? What did the recent update contain?  What video card does your system use?

Please update your question to include this information, do not post it in comments.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Updated.

Comment: Thanks.  A lot of people had trouble with the latest kernel pushed out (the -116) if they had kernel drivers installed, because a specific version of the compiler (gcc) is required.  Some people had other versions of the compiler installed; on my system, the required compiler was pushed out *after* the kernel update.  I don't know enough about your system's graphics to know if this is what happened to you, but you can look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008681/virtualbox-not-starting-after-kernel-upgrade/1009198#1009198 to see how people fixed similar problems.

Comment: I tried downgrading the kernel, to no avail.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I ended up just doing a full reinstall, so it is working again. Would it be safe to update now (was the issue you described something that was likely fixed)?

Comment: I would think so, but I am no expert.

Comment: No expert, but know more than I. It doesn't matter much if it breaks again so I'll go for it. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out it did break it again. Hopefully they'll fix it soon.