# VirtualBox halt on first startup

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version and trying to install VirtualBox.

I installed VirtualBox from command line many times and also today (05.03.2018). The installed version is 5.0.

I set-up the virtual machine. When I start it, the VirtualBox shows this message "You have Auto-capture keyboard option turned on. This will cause ...." and whole system is halted (my own laptop / host computer). I am unable to do anything after this point.

I tried to download the DEB file from [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) website and install it; but it is not working either. It does not open Ubuntu Software and when I click the DEB file, nothing happens.

Can anyone please let me know that I am doing wrong?

[image: Here is the picture of the error]

Comment: I have tried sudo apt-get update but it does not help.

Comment: Sounds like you assigned too many things to the VM.  What are the specs of the computer, and can you provide a screenshot of the VM configuration (CPUs assigned, etc.) so that we can compare what you have available and what you're assigning, to better help you with configuring the VM?

Comment: Here is my host computer:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/K3wqfbN0qQJytJXS2


I have deleted the whole VirtualBox now but I had following specs with the VM:

RAM: 10Gb
CPU: 4
OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
Memory: 120Gb

Comment: When you say "memory" you mean disk space, correct?  Also, try reducing the number of CPUs to 2 - you should never, in Virtualbox, assign more CPUs than you have physical cores in the system (and the x 8 just means you have hyperthreading enabled though you only have 4 physical cores).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I meant disk space :)
I tried it with 2 CPUs and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using gdebi. It will resolve dependiencies for .deb files. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Then use

```
sudo gdebi packagename.deb
```

in the correct directory.

With that said, virtualbox has given me the same issue on Ubuntu, but I didn't install the .deb file, but instead went with an alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
```

I've used both hypervisors and other vm software and this product works very well and is supported by Ubuntu's Server team.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm running an i7 and 16 gb of ram,  so I know it's a problem with Oracle's drivers, not lack of power.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been using the QEMU. It really works fine for me also. But I needed the Guest Auditions to copy and paste the commands. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical problem on both Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 - including the total freeze. As far as I remember, the problem was somehow related to a meltdown/spectre "fix". The solution was to follow the instructions under **Debian-based Linux distributions** on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and eventually install virtualbox-5.2. Also see solution here: [virtualbox crash on kernel 4.13.0-26](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994315/virtualbox-crash-on-kernel-4-13-0-26).

Comment: I think I was the third party repositories. I followed the steps and now it is working! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Just to add that the link was not working due to some reason. But I searched and found it easily! :)