# Accidentally deleted then reinstalled kernel- Want to check I'm ok

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I accidently seem to have deleted my kernel (not sure how I did it) but I noticed before I rebooted the machine and have tried to reinstall it. I just want to be sure I'm ok before I do a reboot. `uname --kernel-release` gave (and still gives) 4.4.0-104-generic.

**How I got in the situation:**

I had no room on my boot folder to update so I removed the defunct image files

I can't find the exact command, but it was something like:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0.{6*, 7*, 8*, 9*, 101, 102, 103}
```

I'm not sure how, but after when I checked with

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ii
```

the list was empty and the image 4.4.104 had been removed. I assume I must have made a typo in my previous command.

**Steps to resolve**

I have yet to reboot the machine, but I did

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic
grub-set-default Ubuntu\,\ with\ Linux\ 4.4.0-108-generic
```

(`sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic` resulted in a 503 error (see below))

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ii
```

Now shows

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic                         4.4.0-104.127~14.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic                         4.4.0-108.131~14.04.1                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

If this is sufficient I will reboot, but I would like to confirm that before I do.

**Further issues:**

When I try

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or to install linux-image-4.4.0.109-generic

I get a list of errors along the lines of

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libruby1.9.1 amd64 1.9.3.484-2ubuntu1.7
  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
```

And nothing gets upgraded.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not a duplicate of that. I have not rebooted and am not stuck at a grub-menu so do not have those issues. I want to know if I'm now safe to reboot or should I do any other steps.

Comment: 108 kernel [may not boot/reboot/suspend/shutdown](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1741934). So you should remove it and install 104 or 109 as described in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/994277/66509). Also you can use `purge-old-kernels` script to remove older kernels.