# Unable to get to GRUB at boot and cannot boot with the default kernel

Tags: 16.04, boot, server, grub2, kernel

My Optiplex 990 with ubuntu server 16.04.3 won't boot. I'm left with a flashing cursor in the top left. I have run into the spectre kernel issue with [Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic)

I have tried following [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) to get into grub, but no amount of tapping / holding shift (or escape as listed elsewhere) has got me into grub.

I tried a live cd and ran boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and that succeeded in running but fixed nothing.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic)

Comment: **To close voters:** OP is obviously aware of https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic and the answers to that question require the use of the Grub boot menu which OP can't reach. Sending them back to that question achieves nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: My mistake. I should add that I specifically mean [this answer about Boot-Repair](/a/326661/175814) which allows changes to the Grub menu display setting. On top of that Boot-Repairs default action unhides the Grub menu. @Zanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top answer to the question you linked to explains how to get into the GRUB menu if pressing shift does not work. You just edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=[some number]`. Then you run `sudo update-grub`.

Since you can't boot at all, you can't do that so easily.

However, you can do it from a live system, so go ahead and boot from a live system as you did before.

Now you can set up a `chroot`. If you're not sure of the device label of your installation's root partition, try running `sudo fdisk -l` to identify it. You should see something in the output like

```
/dev/sda2 <numbers indicating size> Linux filesystem
```

Try mounting that partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

where `sdXY` is the correct label. Then have a look to see if the mounted partition has the directories you expect to see in your root partition:

```
ls /mnt
```

If you see things like this (not necessarily exactly like this, but at least most of them)

```
bin    dev   mnt         root        sys   var
boot   etc   lost+found  opt         run   srv  tmp 
home   lib   media       proc        sbin  usr
```

then you got the right partition.

If you have a separate boot partition, you will need to mount it. If you are not sure, check the file `/mnt/etc/fstab` to see if it has a partition mounted on `/boot`. **Ignore** any mention of a partition mounted on `/boot/efi`.

If you have a separate boot partition, mount it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot
```

where `sdXY` is the correct label of the boot partition.

We might need to bind some additional resources (I am not sure this is necessary in this case):

```
for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount --bind /$d /mnt/$d; done
```

OK, now enter the chroot

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now we can act as if we are in our installed system. First let's edit the configuration file:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

(or call your favourite text editor). Find the line

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

(it may have a different number, but that is not important). Comment out the line by placing `#` at the start of it, so it says

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

If you do not have the above line, look for

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

and comment that out instead to

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

check that the line

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=[some number]
```

ends in a number greater than 0 (the default may be 10). Save the file and exit.

Run this command to write the configuration to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you can reboot into your installation, and the GRUB menu will be forced to come up every time.

Comment: Fantastically thorough. Though I think my system's a lost cause. The first step, finding the Linux partition. When I mount it I don't get any of the directories. I only get a list like abi-4.4.0-104-generic, abi-4.4.0-108-generic, boot-sav etc. Shown in https://imgur.com/a/yLj9O. No other partition can mount as mnt, so it's definitely the right one. I think it's going to have to be reinstalled

Comment: @edwardmlyte that's the boot partition. You may be able to edit the file there  `grub/grub.cfg` directly to force grub to appear. Change the line `set timeout_style=hidden` to `set timeout_style=menu` and `set timeout=0` to `set timeout=10` (about 80-90 lines down I guess?) Then just reboot, no need to chroot. I didn't recommend that before as it's risky to edit the file directly (it will be somewhat unique to your system) but try it before reinstallation!

Comment: Perfect. Once grub loaded I could update the kernel. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear you solved it @edwardmlyte