# Ubuntu 16.04 Server black screen after grub

Tags: boot, server, grub2, raid, btrfs

I'm having issues with my server, one day it was working fine then the next I was experiencing this issue were after the GRUB screen, it goes straight to a black screen and does nothing, no error, no nothing.

My drive set up is 4tb drives, in BTRFS raid

I'm able to see Ubuntu in grub

When I boot into the "Try ubuntu" I'm able to mount the drives (it did this automatically) and i'm able to access the content within them.

So the question is have you any idea how to solve this issue so I can boot back into my server. If there is anything you need to see, tell me what you need me to do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with the latest kernel update (4.4.0-108) I downgraded to 104, then installed the latest kernel update 109

The answer to this question: [Kernel panic after update to 4.4.0-108-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994067/kernel-panic-after-update-to-4-4-0-108-generic) solved it for me