# How to lock down one specific kernel out of several

Tags: kernel, synaptic

I am currently on kernel 4.13.0-38-generic and I am happy to stay on the upgrade path, but I want to keep kernel 4.4.0-119-generic as-is (because virtualbox works for me on that one).

Using synaptic, I have locked the following.

- linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic

Will that be sufficient or is there more that I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

For virtualbox you should install DKMS package:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

## You should not pin kernel versions as they contain security and stability fixes! Meltdown & Spectre as examples.

### Continue only if you are completely sure what you are doing.

For kernel packages pinning see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/999041/66509).

If you understand what you are going to achieve (with lowering security, of course) - you should pin the following packages:

- linux-headers-4.4.0-119
- linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-headers-generic
- linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-image-generic
- linux-tools-4.4.0-119
- linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic
- linux-libc-dev
- linux-libc-dev:i386
- linux-tools-common
- linux-source
- linux-source-4.4.0

To make Synaptic and APT pins consistent (see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002760/66509)):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apt/preferences.d/synaptic /var/lib/synaptic/preferences
```

Comment: The reason I want to run 4.4.0-119 is that that was the last kernel that I could run VirtualBox with (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1764935) and I need to be able to run Microsoft Word/Excel until I have upskilled myself to use LibreOffice Writer/Calc.

Comment: I recommend to use VirtualBox from [Oracle repository](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). It is newer and runs normally with any kernel.

Comment: I know, but not on my hardware (I tried).  Problem is that Oracle has been phasing out support for 'raw mode' and my box needs that.