# Is it safe to automatically install security updates?

Tags: 18.04, updates, security, update-manager, preferences

In the "Software & Updates" preferences, there is an option to automatically download and install security updates:

[image: screenshot]

It seems like this is a very reasonable option. I won't have to bother with updates for two weeks and everything will be done automatically in the background. However, I wonder if it is safe, too? What if I logout or reboot at a wrong time during the installation, because I don't even know there is an installation running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Ubuntu from shutdown before background automatic updates complete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702156/prevent-ubuntu-from-shutdown-before-background-automatic-updates-complete)

Comment: Re. "What if I logout or reboot at a wrong time during the installation,", I suspect you'll see some sort of message if you try to logout. As for rebooting, I guess the same would apply if you use the GUI. I don't know about what would happen if you long-press the power button or switch off the main supply, etc. But do read the linked possible duplicate even though it's a bit dated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some latest "updates" show that **it is not safe**.

You can get:

- kernel panic - see [example 1](https://askubuntu.com/q/994067/66509) or  [example 2](https://askubuntu.com/q/999000/66509)
- [broken USB 3.0](https://askubuntu.com/q/1099414/66509)
- [broken console login](https://askubuntu.com/q/1113704/66509)
- [broken VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/1126591/66509)

So I considered to install updates on my machines manually after reading some feedback about latest updates.
You can always [disable `unattended-upgrades`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006199/66509) to make Ubuntu act as Ubuntu and not Window$ 10.
Do it only if you are sure.