# xubuntu 17.10.1 won't boot after upgrade

Tags: boot, updates, xubuntu

xubuntu 17.10.1 32bit on a HP Pavilion DV4-1612la laptop (Pentium T400, 3 GB of RAM). Install OK, then reboot fine, going for the updates.
Launch Software updater and chose all marked updates.
After next reboot, grub menu shows up. 
Pick ubuntu and system reboots, going into grub menu again. 
This goes on and on.

So far, the only way I found around this is:
Reinstall everything.
Restart xUbuntu
sudo apt-get update (required to install synaptic)
DO NOT pay attention to the Updater notifications.
Installed programs I need.
Now It boots OK.

It there something in the updates causing this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

If you are able to boot with an older kernel version (via grub) you can solve it with:

[Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry/216420)