# How can I work around the tty login bug?

Tags: 18.04, login

BUG: Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS tty1 "Login Incorrect"
[Userspace break as a result of missing patch backport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873)

As I understand the bug: upgrading the kernel has introduced a bug which has made it impossible to enter a password and log in.

Solutions:

1. Move back to previous kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic
   ```
2. Move forward to kernel 4.18.0-15-generic using Linux commands.

Problem: How can I access my home Web Server when I am unable to log in to the terminal screen? I can manage Linux files using FileZilla on a Windows PC but have not set up sshd (PUTTY) to run Linux commands.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Ur solution (2) would work fine, but consider using ssh meanwhile if you need canonical live patching, i would rather stay at 4.15.0-45, it should be fixed pretty soon:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873/comments/29

If you configured FileZilla with sftp, ssh will most likely work with PuTTY, use same port and credentials.

Comment: Many thanks Jesse. I have installed PUTTY and it runs ok. I have three kernels installed 4.15.0.39 4.15.0.44 4.15.0.45-generic. My server boots directly to the tty screen. Can I catch the Grub Menu and select the  4.15.0.39 kernel? The Grub Menu is not displayed normally.

Comment: @KevinGordon please see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: Please see my answer below which has additional questions.

Comment: @charlesgreen I edited /etc/default/grub and changed GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 (was 2) then GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu (was hidden) then ran command update-grub. Rebooted server: grub menu appeared: Selected Advanced Options: Selected Linux-4.15.0.39-generic (was Linux-4.15.0.45-generic). Login via console ok.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following commands in this order:

sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic

sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic

sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic

I then reboot and uname -a confirmed the default kernel is linux-4.15.0-43-generic