# Set advanced option as default ( = 0) startup in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, upstart

I have an installation of Ubuntu 16.04 that only boots properly under an advanced option in GRUB (upstart). I know that you can rank the order of boot options from the grub menu, with 0 being the default, but I need to choose an advanced option in this case. Does anyone know how I can set an advanced option, i.e. how they are numbered?

For some background, I'm doing this so that I can reboot from a remote shell, where I can't choose grub options.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the accepted answer at [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line that contains GRUB_DEFAULT - this is what you'll want to edit to set the default. You must know the full name of the kernel you want - e.g. Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-53-generic - along with the full name of the "advanced menu" - e.g. Advanced options for Ubuntu.

You then combine those two strings with > and set GRUB_DEFAULT to them as: GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-53-generic" (including quotes).

Save it, then build the updated grub menu.

`sudo update-grub`