# Unable to switch Linux boot order via SSH

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssh

I have to Linux dist installed on two separate HDDs,
currently I' m working from home so sometimes need to switch OS back and forth.
I tried all these steps from this link:

[Set “older” kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry/1258979?noredirect=1#comment2127985_1258979)

but nothing works for me.

Each time Debian 9 Stretch being loaded.
How can I switch to Ubuntu OS ?

Here is my setup

[image]

Here is the disk configuration. I need to boot OS from /dev/sdb1.

[image]

Comment: You are probably going from this grub into grub on the other disk which then sends you back to this OS.  What is the disk configuration look like? I wonder if you can change this grub to point to /dev/sdb2 instead of /dev/sdb1.

Comment: @rtaft I' ve just posted disk config in the topic.

Comment: Can you mount `/dev/sdb1` and view `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to see if it is pointing back to sda?

Comment: How can I examine /boot/grub/grub.cfg to figure out where is it pointing to ?

Comment: Remotely?  First mount it, `sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu` and `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/ubuntu`, Then view `/media/ubuntu/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and look at the line `set default` to see what it says, I think that's the setting to look at.

Comment: currently set default is `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi`

Comment: By the way , which one grub.cfg, do I need to examine? `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or  `{mount_point_of_sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg` ? Which one will be used during boot process?

Comment: Can you post both to a pastbin so we can examine both?  I really don't know which one is getting executed first.

Comment: Amazing on the HDD (dev/sdb1, `{mount_point_of_sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg` ) where is the Ubuntu installed set default point to `set default="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) (on /dev/sda3)"`

Comment: Reinstall the bootloader to both MBRs to make sure Debians Grub is used (`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`). Set default in Debians Grub to boot Ubuntu. When booted into Ubuntu and you want to reboot into debian do the same in Ubuntu (reinstall bootloader to both MBR) and configure Ubuntus Grub to default to Debian.

Comment: @mook765 I don't clearly understand how to do second step you suggest: `Set default in Debians Grub to boot Ubuntu.` Actually, currently, changing `/etc/default/grub` has no effect at all. i.e. always Debian(/dev/sdaX) being loaded.

Comment: That's why you should reinstall the bootloader to both MBR, obviously the wrong bootloader is used ( the one from Ubuntu which will not look for it's config in Debian). In `/etc/default/grub` set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` (that should be Ubuntu entry), run `sudo update-grub`, reinstall the bootloader (see previous comment), reboot.

Comment: @mook765, Ok, currently I was able to boot proper OS. But not exactly in the way you suggested. I will post an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rtaft and @mook765 for helping.
I'm not very experiencing in grub internals, and actually I don't have much desire to read tons of documentation.

In my case I have to HDD:

- /dev/sda - Debian
- /dev/sdb - Ubuntu.

Both of these have their own copy of /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
Let's say I login to Debian now, it means all commands like
`sudo grub-update sudo grub-set-default x`

etc. will affect grub.cfg of Debian dist currently running.

Taking into account, that I don't know order of executing of these two versions of grub.cfg. I decided to change line with set default="Desired OS", in my case
`set default="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) (on /dev/sda3)"`

for BOTH these grub.cfg.

Summary:

1. I changed `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually and set desired default.
2. I mount second HDD (/dev/sdb -> ~/mnt_devsdb).
3. I changed `~/mnt_devsdb/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually and set desired default(the same as for p.1).
4. reboot and .... voila! it works!

To boot Ubuntu I need to repeat all these steps and set proper default again.