# System's speakers not detected anymore on ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.8.1

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, amd-graphics

My speakers stopped working on my Lenovo IdeaPad 14ARE15. They are not it seems detected anymore (see picture). Any idea on what could cause this / possible fixes ?

Thanks in advance,

Kernel

```
5.8.1-050801-generic #202008111432 SMP Tue Aug 11 14:34:42 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Info on audio

```
lspci -knn | grep -iA2 audio
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3816]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
04:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [17aa:3822]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
04:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [17aa:3823]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

pulseaudio

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

[image: Output device showing HDMI...]

Comment: Not exactly a slution as it dosen't adress the actual issue but a quick fix is to rollback your kernel. Choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" from GRUB and choose the previous  working kernel. Then do this to keep it as default https://askubuntu.com/a/1000735/75060 and reboot.

Comment: Thanks but on previous kernels I had other issues such as not being able to change my screen's brightness, or bluetooth not working ect... So overall the 5.8.1 was the one with the least problems. The main ones being this speaker problem and the touchpad sometimes not working