# Virtualbox broken after a dist-upgrade -- cannot install virtuabox-dkms nor run modprobe vboxdrv

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, dkms, modprobe

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and recently did a dist-upgrade.

```
uname -r: 5.8.0-34-generic
```

I purged Virtualbox and associate files by:

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
```

After trying to reinstall any software I get the following now:

```
>>$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,236 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 328260 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic_5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) over (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.8.0-34-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.0-34-generic -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup err
or from a previous failure.
                           Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Does not fix the dependency problem. I still get the same output:

```
>>$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Reconfiguring as below yields the same message:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The crash report located at /var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash indicates the following:

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for virtualbox-6.1.10 for kernel 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
 Thursday, January 07, 2021 AM09:37:43 HKT
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic'
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
 In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
                  from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:556,
                  from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                  from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                  from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:79,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘supdrvOSChangeCR4’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: error: ‘cpu_tlbstate’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘cpuhp_state’?
   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
 ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
   318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
       |         ^~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
 ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
   318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
       |         ^~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
   760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
 make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 5.8.0-34-generic
Date: Thu Jan  7 09:37:46 2021
DuplicateSignature: dkms:virtualbox-dkms:6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1:/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: error: ‘cpu_tlbstate’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘cpuhp_state’?
Package: virtualbox-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1
PackageVersion: 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1
SourcePackage: virtualbox
Title: virtualbox-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1: virtualbox kernel module failed to build
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

After input from @Terrace and others, I tried installing from source. But I still get an error in installing virtualbox-dkms. After that, I uninstalled virtual-dkms directly:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
```

And then re-attempted the install

````
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

Wich succeeded. Thank you!
````

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, why are you using the 5.8 kernel? as Ubuntu 20.04.1 is still on the 5.4 kernel.  Are you running Ubuntu or Pop OS?

Comment: Ubuntu... I got an update notification, did apt-get upgrade... said that some of the linux-generic-hwe-20.04 packages had been held back.I had had some problems with not being able to recognize my HDMI connections, and was just hoping some upgrade would help... do I went ahead and did a dist-upgrade... I do not follow closely which dists are the newest or appropriate... so I just went ahead.

Comment: Mine is still working fine with the 5.8.0-34-generic kernel, but I installed mine from the `.deb` file supplied by Virtualbox themselves:  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads which is version 6.1.16.  That makes me wonder if the 6.1.10 version in the Repos needs to be updated to work with the new kernel update.

Comment: Do you have the virtualbox source files installed? In the output posted it complains about missing ```virtualbox-source```.

Comment: I agree: I got a kernel upgrade in ubuntu 20.04 to kernel 5.8 ... I'm struggling to get this to work again ....

Comment: Also have gotten `linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic` by `apt upgrade` on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'll rather downgrade the kernel and see if that works before starting with source downloads.

Comment: NB! Remove the `5.8.0` kernel and revert to the older kernel. The `5.8.0` kernel seems to be removed from upgrade now. I got VirtualBox working again and I'll try to write it up in a post.

Answer (score 18):

## Update

**Note:**
 <s>- This guide will become irrelevant in the near future when `proposed` migrates to `release`.</s>

- **6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1 is now in the Store 'ubuntu-focal-updates-multiverse' and 5.8 kernel had a few updates with current 5.8.0-40-generic**
  **Should not be an issue if one keeps up with regular updates.**

---

- Suggested options 1 and 4 to have future automatic updates for VirtualBox.
- Option 2, 3a, 3b *manual installation* **does not** include automatic future updates for VirtualBox.

---

Bug

- [[SRU] virtualbox 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 ADT test failure with linux-hwe-5.8 5.8.0-25.26~20.04.1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1901904)
- [virtualbox 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1 source package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/6.1.16-dfsg-6%7Eubuntu1.20.04.1)

### Installation of VirtualBox 6.1.16 on Ubuntu 20.04

#### Option 1 (Easy)

Pre-released updates (focal-proposed)

1. - Open `Software & Updates`
   - `Developer Options`
   - select ✅ `Pre-released updates (focal-proposed)`
   - select `Close`
   - on Popup `The information about available software is out-of-date`
     select `Reload`
2. - Open `Software Updater`
   - deselect all/any other updates except `VirtualBox` (which will include multiple packages in its subcategory)
   - select `Install Now`
3. - **Repeat step 1** to disable `Pre-released updates (focal-proposed)`
     You don't want to update other `proposed updates` unless you are familiar with what it entails.
     *Ref.*  [Testing/EnableProposed - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed),  [ProposedMigration - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ProposedMigration)

---

## Previous post

Bug
[virtualbox-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 fails to build with kernel 5.8](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1891916)
I followed [@Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) advice and installed 6.1.16 from the source.
My previous VMs are all working.

Edit: Per [@BeastOfCaerbannog](https://askubuntu.com/users/618353/beastofcaerbannog) request/suggestion.

---

### Installation of VirtualBox 6.1.16 on Ubuntu 20.04

#### Option 2 (Easy)

- Go to [Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)
- Under **VirtualBox 6.1.16 for Linux**
  Click [Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961%7EUbuntu%7Eeoan_amd64.deb)
- Open with GDebi Package Installer
- Install Package

**if* GDebi *is not installed* > go to Software Store and install it
**if Error: Conflicts with the installed package 'virtualbox-qt'* > go to Software Store and Remove Virtualbox 6.1.10

---

#### Option 3 a. (Easy)

- Go to [Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)
- Under **VirtualBox 6.1.16 for Linux**
  Click [Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961%7EUbuntu%7Eeoan_amd64.deb)
- Save File in Downloads
- Go to Downloads
- Right Click downloaded package > Open With Software install (or double click, or select and enter/return)
- Install

#### Option 3 b. (Advanced)

- In Terminal

```
cd Downloads
```

```
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

or

```
sudo apt install ./v*
```

---

#### Option 4 (Advanced)

[Install Virtualbox by using the Virtualbox repos](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305883/231142)

*thanks [@Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance)*

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you elaborate on how you installed 6.1.16 from source? This would make your answer much more useful!

Comment: Yesterday I wrote up this answer how to install Virtualbox by using the Virtualbox repos:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1305883/231142  Feel free to use it if you want in your answer as well.  =)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! The direct link to download for Ubuntu 20.04 gets an outdated version though. I was having issues with version 6.1.26 installed from apt, and the link gave me version 6.1.16. Going to downloads page you linked and selecting the Ubuntu 20.04 link gave me version 6.1.32.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the latest working 5.4 kernel instead.

I have 20.04 and this worked for me:

`sudo grub-reboot "1>4"`

`sudo reboot`

Or just manually choose the 5.4 kernel at boot.

I guess this bug will be fixed for Ubuntus 5.8 kernel soon.

Answer (score 0):

After input from @Terrace and others, I tried installing from source. But I still get an error in installing virtualbox-dkms. After that, I uninstalled virtual-dkms directly:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
```

And then re-attempted the install:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

Which succeeded. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox is directly installable from the ubuntu repositories, so there is no need to fiddle around with Virtualbox downloads, dkms etc. This is all taken care of by the ubuntu packages, including the dkms stuff WITH SECURE BOOT WORKING in case you have it activated and your MOK keys properly installed!!

You install it simply by `sudo apt install virtualbox`

On Ubuntu 20.04 you usually have kernel 5.4 and virtualbox comes there in version 6.1.10.

With Ubuntu 20.10 you have kernel 5.8 and virtualbox 6.1.14. Both work flawlessly on my machines.

Give it a try! ;-)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The 5.8.0 kernel seems to be buggy and is no longer part of the upgrade. If it is installed and things fail, it has to be removed.

1. Boot an older kernel
2. Remove the `5.8.0` kernel
3. Fix issues with nvidia drivers (my issue, ymmv)

## Boot an older kernel

I prefered to make it possible to select a kernel at boot. There are different paths for this but I chose to change the boot menu from `hidden` to `menu` and increase the timeout.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
...
$ grep GRUB_TIMEOUT /etc/default/grub
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
#GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Remember to update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

## Reboot and select older kernel

A menu is now presented on boot, select "Advanced ..." and select an older kernel (`5.4.0-60-generic` in my case).

After booting I had to update grub again for the menu setting to keep.

```
sudo update-grub
```

## Remove the "new" / failing kernel

List installed kernel versions. APT warns that it is not "script friendly", i.e. output *can* vary, so use scripts with care.

```
# 
sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep -o -E "^linux[^/]+5.8.0-[^/]+"
```

Remove linux-headers

```
# First remove linux-headers so that modprobe won't fail on virtualbox
# I had to remove these versions, your list might differ.
sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic
sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic
```

Then remove remaining kernel packages

```
# NB! Handle with care.
# Do this ONLY if you are comfortable, or prepare a list and run one by one.
sudo apt remove $(sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep -o -E "^linux[^/]+5.8.0-[^/]+")
```

Reboot, before starting to fix Nvidia drivers (if applicable to you).

## Fix Nvidia drivers

After reverting the kernel my screen setup did not work - external monitors did not load. So I removed the Nvidia packages, booted, then installed them again.

```
sudo apt remove $(sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | grep -o -E "^nvidia[^/]")
# Remove packages now no longer needed
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot - I did this to make absolutely sure of a clean system. You *might* be able to skip this.

Install Nvidia drivers again.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

Rebooted, and now my external monitors came back to life.

## Verify that packages are resolved

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

## Start Virtualbox and Virtualbox guests.

My VirtualBox guests now started.
I did not touch virtualbox at all during this process, only the kernel (and graphics driver).

## Revert grub changes

Now would be the time to revert the Grub changes if you would rather skip the wait-for-menu, or bar this opportunity if your PC is in an office space where others have access physically.

Answer (score 0):

I
managed to solve this by the following instruction

The first step is to remove all currently installed VirtualBox

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms # i have to remove manually
```

Download new version from [page](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961%7EUbuntu%7Eeoan_amd64.deb)

Close all running VirtualBox instances

Install by running the following command :

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

When tried install with apt I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

I personally couldn't get it running in 5.8.0 at all, so I decided to downgrade, and it's usually as easy as following @sastorsi answer, just selecting an older kernel at boot from the GRUB, but I went berserk trying to fix this and ended up with no older kernels.
If you also happen to have no usable kernels, you can install the latest 5.4.0 with the following command:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-60 linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic
```

And if you're having trouble with HDMI, WIFI, etc. you must install the kernel modules (I actually ended up reinstalling ubuntu because I didn't know this):

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic
```

Then remove the buggy kernel:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic && sudo apt autoremove
```

If it doesn't boot into the desired kernel automatically, you can either choose it at boot from the GRUB, or you can make GRUB pick a specific version with this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/216420/873251).
Basically all you have to do is add `"Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-60-generic"` to the `GRUB_DEFAULT` line, it should look something like this: `GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-60-generic"`

And finally you should be able to install Virtualbox as usual:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
```