# Error with virtualbox-guest-dkms

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I have just installed ubuntu on VirtualBox 6.1.16. I started trying to configure, and after running the following command: `$ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms` I receive the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox-guest-dkms is already the newest version (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-guest-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-guest-dkms.0.crash'rogress: [ 33%] [#######################.................................................] 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-guest-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-guest-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-guest-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, when trying to setup sublime text following the steps from the website, typing `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` gives the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.0.2ubuntu0.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-guest-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-guest-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-guest-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-guest-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-guest-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-guest-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What could this be, and what should I do about it (if anything)?

Comment: It is a bug with 5.8 kernel and Virtualbox 6.1.10.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305873/error-installing-virtualbox-dkms-on-ubuntu-20

Comment: I am using Virtualbox Version 6.1.16, but it seems like the proposed solution was to install 6.1.16 (updated the question now).

Comment: OK, I see.  The `virtualbox-guest-dkms` is still only 6.1.10 which will not work with 5.8.  Why are you trying to install the guest-dkms?

Comment: I was following a tutorial to enable drag & drop features between guest & host. That isn't essential, but I also tried installing sublime text and received a similar error (updated the original post).

Comment: Not all "tutorials" are good.

Comment: @Pilot6 indeed, but it worked a few months ago with no issue, and I would not have figured it out myself as I am quite new to using Ubuntu.

Comment: A few months ago there was the 5.4 kernel, that could work with old additions. But generally it is a wrong way to install them.

Comment: Ok, well the features I was after are installed anyway. However I'm still receiving a similar message when attempting to install sublime text (see my edit). Again, it seems to still install sublime but I'm not sure if I need to do something about this error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can ask another question about sublime. It is a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed VirtualBox 6.1.16, you shouldn't install `virtualbox-guest-dkms` from Ubuntu repos.

You need to mount Guest Additions form the machine menu (Devices) and install the correspondent 6.1.16 Guest Additions.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest,
This solved my issue.
It's just that you installed a previous version of virtual-guest that is locked. You need to purge it to get it updated.

> sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-guest-dkms

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot with the latest working 5.4 kernel.

Then it will work.

Hopefully the 5.8 bug is fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

even after mounting Guest Additions form the machine menu (Devices) and install the correspondent 6.1.16 Guest Additions as @Pilot6 mentioned, whenever you try to update or install a software you'll probably see something like this

```
sudo apt install htop
[sudo] password for asarkar-vrt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
htop is already the newest version (2.2.0-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe (6.1.16-dfsg-6ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Removing old virtualbox-guest-6.1.16 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.16
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-guest-6.1.16 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-7620-generic
Building initial module for 5.11.0-7620-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-7620-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-7620-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-guest/6.1.16/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but if you just simply run this command the problem goes away.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe
```

you can install anything after this but won't see that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the most reliable solution is manually running the guest additions like with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
cd /mnt/cdrom
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```