# Oracle VM. Error processing package virtualbox-dkms (dpkg) after upgrading kernel headers

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, dpkg, dkms

After a standard upgrade, I am no longer able to use my virtualbox.
I get the following error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

After reinstalling virtualbox-dkms I also get an error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic ()
```

Any ideas?
I know many people have already had this error but none of their solutions have worked for me.

EDIT

Make.log file shows the following errors:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-6.1.10 for kernel 5.8.0-36-generic ()
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:556,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:79,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘supdrvOSChangeCR4’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: error: ‘cpu_tlbstate’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘cpuhp_state’?
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone just had the same issue today and if anyone wanting to find the solution gets to this post first, I recommend you to head on here: [Error installing virtualbox-dkms on Ubuntu 20](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305873/error-installing-virtualbox-dkms-on-ubuntu-20?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Choose the latest working 5.4 kernel instead.

I have 20.04 and this worked for me:

`sudo grub-reboot "1>4"`

`sudo reboot`

Or just manually choose the 5.4 kernel at boot.

I guess this bug will be fixed for 5.8 soon.