# Ubuntu 20.04.1LTS VirtualBox E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg

After an ubuntu update my virtualbox could not load my windows 10 VM, everytime i tried to open it it shows me this error:
[vbox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD8WZ.png)

I followed many tutorials, could not get it running. Ended up re-installing ubuntu, but i still have the same issue after installing vbox.

I am worried that, there are many tutorials on how to solve it online, and i have picked some of the wrong ones, since i have not tried them all.
Any ideas?

After installing vbox, if i try to install another app like lets say 'git', it succeeds, but gives me these errors:

```
soldy@soldy:~$ sudo apt-get install git
[sudo] password for soldy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk
  gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5464 kB of archives.
After this operation, 38,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17029-1 [26,5 kB]
Get:2 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3 [884 kB]
Get:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3 [4554 kB]
Fetched 5464 kB in 2s (2634 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
(Reading database ... 177558 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.25.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up git (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                     dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See thsi answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1305883/77093

Answer (score 2):

You should remove 6.1.10 and install 6.1.16. Take a look at this link to download latest version https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads. You are probably experiencing this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1891916