# VirtualBox does no longer work on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kernel, virtualbox, crash

VirtualBox 6.1 works no longer on my Ubuntu 20.0.4.1 LTS.

It says:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.

I am using the Ubuntu version of VirtualBox. I tried to re-install VirtualBox with the synaptic package manager, but ran into other problems, meaning VB can no longer be installed.

It was working properly until the last kernel update a week ago.

Comment: This happened to me (and everyone who got the kernel ugraded in ubunut). There is a bug with virtualbox 6.1.10 and it does not work with kernel 5.8. Go back to kernel 5.4 and  the issue goes away... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel

Comment: You can either go back to kernel 5.4 **or** you can install Virtualbox directly from Virtualbox themselves to get version 6.1.16 that works fine with kernel 5.8:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1305883/231142  Either way is the right answer.

Comment: @Terrance, yes, I agree, either way is ok. But I prefer to stick with virtualbox as provided by the repositories of ubuntu, it's my personal option. Eventually the new virtualbox 6.1.16 will be available in the repositories ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, and sadly I am not the only one affected. My personal solution was to install VB directly, since the 5.4 kernels were no longer available. Lets hope 6.1.16 makes it into Ubuntu quickly.