# Hibernate lost after update to kernel version

Tags: hibernate, tuxonice

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed (due to Petalinux requirement) where Hibernation so far at least worked. Recently I got an update notice, confirmed it and am now running on this version:

$ uname -a
Linux datatel-XMG-CORE-M19-GTX-1650 5.4.0-77-generic #86~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 18 01:23:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Before the update, using kernel 5.4.0.74 a "sudo hibernate" worked fine. Now it does not, instead returns a black screen for a sec and then:
hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.

Looking for help on that I saw several posts proposing to adapt /sys/power/state, adding "disk" and "standby" to it. I have tried that in any possible way I could think of, using vi directly on the file, writing it with an "echo..." command, making up a file in my home and then copying to that location using "sudo cp ~/<file> /sys/power/state".
Neither of this works. I always get a permission error. I have even tried to "chmod" all the directories to "777" and that was successful looking at "ls -la" but nothing helps.

Help would really be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please file a bug report for this apparent regression.

Comment: *Thank you for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu better*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: No, thanks, I meanwhile solved it.
It was the "Secure Boot" enabled in the UEFI/BIOS settings which disabled the hibernation.
But the two other problems, the "Tuxonice binary signature file not found." and that I am not able to write/change anything in /sys/power remains. I have put that in the bug report to the Ubuntu team.

Comment: This question should be closed/removed. It is misleading as I've made the wrong assumptions.