# New Ubuntu kernel is causing a black scree, whereas the older kernel doesn't

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I restarted Ubuntu to be faced with the black screen of death, after some trial and error I found out that the older Kernel (5.11.0-27-generic) worked perfectly fine, but whenever I would turn on my pc and boot the default Ubuntu choice, I would be met with the newer version (5.11.0-43-generic).

I've tried using all of the versions of nomodeset and I'm pretty stuck. I'll try as much as I can to fix it for the newest version, but if all of this doesn't work I want to make the older kernel to boot as default so that I don't have to select the option with quick hands.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & release details; but switching to the alternate kernels tack maybe an easy fix (ie. Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stack choices; GA is the most stable and HWE for newer hardware).

Comment: @guiverc I provided the os, which is Ubuntu, and what is a kernel tack as well? When I google it I just get a correction for kernel stack.

Comment: Ubuntu offers many products; and a number use the 5.11 kernel so we don't know which you're using.  Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core?  and what release of Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc has yet to be provided.  Sorry "*tack*" was a typo made; Ubuntu offers two *kernel stack* choices for LTS releases; GA being the *stable* or HWE which changes during the life of the product; eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server uses the GA or 5.4 kernel by default; however Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (depending on media used to install) defaults to the HWE stack, which changes from 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 etc

Comment: What hardware do you have in your system?  NVIDIA card drivers when installed from NVIDIA and not from Ubuntu do not install DKMS drivers that carry over into a new kernel.

Comment: @Terrance The thing is I can't boot the new kernel, I'll install the nvidia drivers on the older version, but I thought it did that for me already, I have the nvidia x server settings, and it shows my gpu and all of the settings for it as well though I'm using Ubuntu desktop. Haw can I just, boot it.

Comment: If you installed the NVIDIA drivers from Ubuntu, then they will show up in the `dkms status` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)