# When I turn off Ubuntu, it shows black screen but it doesn't power off

Tags: power-management, shutdown

When I try to turn off my laptop everything goes fine and it shows black screen, but it doesn't power off, and the only thing I can do is to power it off manually.
I tried turning off with `poweroff -f` or `shutdown -h now` but nothing change.

This problem appeared for the first time on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Then I tried to reinstall the same same version of Ubuntu but the problem was still there. I tried installing Ubuntu 21.10, but nothing changed.
In the end I tried a different distribution (Pop!_OS) and it power off normally.
I'm using a Acer Aspire 3 A315-21-92HJ with AMD A9-9420, 8 GB RAM and a 250GB SSD.

EDIT ---

I include the log file obtained with `tac /var/log/syslog > ~/log.txt`:

```
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Hold until boot process finishes up.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: plymouth-quit-wait.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus kernel: [ 1444.798835] audit: type=1400 audit(1641401796.100:118): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/cmdline" pid=700 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus kernel: [ 1444.798776] audit: type=1400 audit(1641401796.100:117): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/1/environ" pid=700 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus kernel: [ 1444.798678] audit: type=1400 audit(1641401796.100:116): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease" pid=700 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus bluetoothd[606]: Terminating
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Modem Manager...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: The offending signal was state-changed on NMDeviceWifi 0x55d645ff4390.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: The offending signal was state-changed on NMDeviceEthernet 0x55d645fee250.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: The offending signal was notify on NMActiveConnection 0x55d645ffd180.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: The offending signal was notify on NMDeviceWifi 0x55d645ff4390.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: message repeated 4 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x55d643bdd1c0 ==]
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d643bdd1c0 ==
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: The offending signal was notify on NMDeviceEthernet 0x55d645fee250.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus ModemManager[714]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus NetworkManager[610]: <info>  [1641401796.0767] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped Monitor Session leader for GNOME Session.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: gnome-session-monitor.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus ModemManager[714]: <info>  caught signal, shutting down...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target System Time Set.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Check to see whether there is a new version of Ubuntu available.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: update-notifier-motd.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: ua-timer.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: motd-news.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Daily man-db regeneration.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: man-db.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Daily rotation of log files.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: logrotate.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: fstrim.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Trigger anacron every hour.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: anacron.timer: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Removed slice system-modprobe.slice.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped GNOME Session Manager (session: ubuntu).
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: gnome-session-manager@ubuntu.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopping Session 2 of user cosimo.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopping GNOME Wacom tablet support service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopping GNOME power management service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopping GNOME keyboard shortcuts service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopping GNOME keyboard configuration service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopping GNOME color management service...
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME XSettings target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME sound sample caching target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME smartcard target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME file sharing target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME RFKill support target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME printer notifications target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME power management target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME keyboard configuration target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME maintenance of expirable data target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME date & time target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME color management target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME accessibility target.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME Session (session: ubuntu).
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME Wayland Session.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME Session.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped Path trigger for new release of Ubuntu notifications.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: update-notifier-release.path: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped Path trigger for Apport crash notifications.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: update-notifier-crash.path: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target Current graphical user session.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: Stopped target GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Unhandled promise rejection. To suppress this warning, add an error handler to your promise chain with .catch() or a try-catch block around your await expression. Stack trace of the failed promise:#012  _seekStatusNotifierItems/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:141:1#012  _seekStatusNotifierItems@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:141:21#012  async*AppIndicatorsStatusNotifierWatcher@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:57:14#012  maybeEnableAfterNameAvailable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:54:33#012  enable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:59:5#012  _callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:168:32#012  loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:351:26#012  _loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:597:18#012  collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:28#012  _loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:572:19#012  _enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:606:18#012  _sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:637:18#012  init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:57:14#012  _initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:278:22#012  start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:175:5#012  @<main>:1:47
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus gnome-shell[1412]: Unhandled promise rejection. To suppress this warning, add an error handler to your promise chain with .catch() or a try-catch block around your await expression. Stack trace of the failed promise:#012  _seekStatusNotifierItems/<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:141:1#012  _seekStatusNotifierItems@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:141:21#012  async*AppIndicatorsStatusNotifierWatcher@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:57:14#012  maybeEnableAfterNameAvailable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:54:33#012  enable@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:59:5#012  _callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:168:32#012  loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:351:26#012  _loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:597:18#012  collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:28#012  _loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:572:19#012  _enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:606:18#012  _sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:637:18#012  init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:57:14#012  _initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:278:22#012  start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:175:5#012  @<main>:1:47
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus systemd[1293]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  5 17:56:35 Gallimimus kernel: [ 1444.612640] rfkill: input handler enabled
```

I turned the pc off at 17:56:35 and I waited until 17:37:35 for the forced power off.

EDIT 2 ---

I include the output of `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 ago 19 12:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 ago 19 12:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 ago 19 12:35 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ago 19 12:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ago 19 12:35 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

EDIT 3 ---
I tried many different things, and I may found something:

From the GRUB menu, choosing `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, I find 4 elements (2 kernel in normal and recovery mode):

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic (recovery mode)

If I choose the third option, and boot normally, my pc power off successfully
If I choose recovery mode for both kernel, and in the next window choose `resume` to boot normally, it power off successfully.
If I choose the first option (which i suppose to be the default kernel), and boot normally, my pc doesn't power off.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to what the system is waiting for when powering off?

Comment: @matigo
If I run tac /var/log/syslog > ~/log.txt the last think it does before I power off manually (and I waited for 1 minute) is: Jan  5 17:56:36 Gallimimus systemd[1]: Stopped Hold until boot process finishes up. However I edit the post including the log file, from the power off command to the forced power off.

Comment: Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema I updated my BIOS to the latest version but nothing changed.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and see if the problem is gone. Report back results. If the problem still occurs, disconnect ALL external USB/bluetooth devices except for the Ubuntu Live USB and retest. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema If I boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, as you suggest, the problem doesn't occur and it power off normally.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Have you made any modifications to the SPLASH screen, GRUB screen, or login page background? Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: @heynnema I edited my question. However the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` is: `ls: cannot access '/home/cosimo/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory`. I haven't made any modification, and I don't haev CPU or RAM overclocked

Comment: @CosimoMassari You may need to **clean** reinstall Ubuntu, but let's try this first. In `terminal` do `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, then `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`, then reboot, retest power off. Report back.

Comment: @CosimoMassari If that doesn't help, try this: log into a different user account (create one if you need to) and see if the problem occurs there too.

Comment: @heynnema I did as you suggested, but nothing changed (furthermore, as expected, even when i reboot the system it get stucked). I also tried using a different account but the problem is still there.
What do you mean with a **clean reinstall** ?

Comment: @CosimoMassari Since the problem occurs with 20.04 and 21.10, but not Ubuntu Live USB or Pop!_OS, the problem is confined to your Ubuntu installation on disk. Backup your important data, and reinstall Ubuntu. Watch carefully, and if you see a small "Format" checkbox, make sure that it's not checked, and that should leave your /home folder alone. If a straight reinstall doesn't fix the problem, we'll have to do that **clean install**, by wiping out the existing Ubuntu, and then doing a fresh install... but don't do that yet... just reinstall and retest.

Comment: @heynnema I've already tried reinstalling my OS several times. In particular after your suggest about the Ubuntu Live USB I installed that system on my pc (20.04 LTS in particular), but the problem still occur.

I've never mentioned before because I thought it wasn't relavant, but at this point maybe is should be.
On my laptop I'm using 2 different hdd with 2 OS, an ssd with Ubuntu, and a hdd with Windows. In order to switch between them I physically remove one hdd and install the other. To do so I aldo need to switch between legacy mode (used with ubuntu), and UEFI mode (for Windows)

Comment: @CosimoMassari You should have BOTH Windows and Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode. You don't need to physically remove/install drives to boot either. Either install them on the same SSD/HDD, or use the GRUB menu, or use the F12 boot menu to select your desired OS. Since Ubuntu is on its own SSD, backup your data, wipe the disk, and do a **clean install** in UEFI mode.

Comment: @heynnema I did a clean install of Ubuntu in UEFI mode on my SSD, but the problem still occur.
I used the mentioned solution because my laptop has only one slot for a hdd, and I have a GB SSD, hence I can't do a partition for the small dimension.
However if you have any other suggestion for this situation, I'm glad to change my mind.

Comment: Wow. I'm stumped. Check for a firmware update for your SSD. If it's a Samsung, download their `Samsung Magician` software. Otherwise, it must be a Acer-specific problem. Contact Acer Support and see if they're willing to assist. Google "Acer Aspire 3 A315 ubuntu shutdown" and see if you can find any help. Let me know if you get it solved.

Comment: See Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema Here's a little update. I tried your suggestion in Update #2, but it didn't worked. Since updating my SSD firmware in Linux is a little of a mess (i'm using a Crucial mx500), i tried installing Ubuntu on a different hdd, and I found the same issue. I contacted Acer Support, hoping for a answer in short time.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: @heynnema Acer support answered: "The Acer Italy assistance service only provides support on the correct functioning of the operating systems pre-installed on the computer as an OEM version and does not perform customizations to the customer." I give up. The only thing I can do now is to install a different Linux distribution, hoping they will fix it in the future...

Comment: @CosimoMassari Yeah, I should have figured that would be their response. Sounds like Pop!_OS is your next step? You might also check Linux Mint.

Comment: @heynnema Please check EDIT 3 in my question, where I added some information and maybe some good news.

Comment: @CosimoMassari Thanks for the update!

Comment: @heynnema I did it !! I changed the default kernel with grub and now my pc work perfectly. I sum up everything I did and I add an answer to my question

Comment: @CosimoMassari Great news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in EDIT 3 of my answer:

From the GRUB menu, choosing Advanced options for Ubuntu, I find 4 elements (2 kernel in normal and recovery mode):

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic (recovery mode)

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic (recovery mode)

If I choose the third option, hence a different kernel, my pc power off successfully.

Since it was a problem of my Acer with that specific kernel (Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic), I simply changed the default kernel following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/216420/1556620).

In my specific case I:

- made a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

- Edited the file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

- Changed the line `GRUB_DEFAULT` from `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic'
```

- Updated grub menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: When using graphical apps with sudo, `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` should be `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` or you may create a log-in loop.

Comment: There's a slight possibility that the Power Manager in your Acer is messed up. Shutdown the Acer, then hold down the POWER button for ~20-30 seconds, then reboot with the -46 kernel, and see if it powers down properly. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your advice. I edited my answer. I tried holding down the POWER button but it changed nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

**BIOS**

Acer Aspire 3 A315-21-92HJ

The BIOS was updated to the latest 1.25 version. It didn't solve the problem.

**SHUTDOWN/POWER OFF**

Since the problem occurs with 20.04 and 21.10, and when logged into a different user account, but does not occur when booted to a Ubuntu Live USB or Pop!_OS, the problem is confined to your Ubuntu installation on disk.

Backup your important data, and reinstall Ubuntu. Watch carefully, and if you see a small "Format" checkbox, make sure that it's not checked, and that should leave your /home folder alone.

If a straight reinstall doesn't fix the problem, we'll have to do that **clean install**, by wiping out the existing Ubuntu, and then doing a fresh install... but don't do that yet... just reinstall and retest.

**Update #1:**

A **clean install** of Ubuntu in UEFI mode didn't fix the problem.

**Update #2:**

**Note**: In your BIOS, check for a setting for "fast boot" or "fast startup". Disable it.

Check these settings in Windows.

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`