# How do I default to an older kernel in GRUB?

Tags: boot, gnu

For whatever reason, the GUI only works when I am on: Ubuntu, Linux 5.15.0-43-generic.

However GRUB boots to Ubuntu, with linux 5.15.0-52-generic automatically. In order to use Ubuntu, I have to access the GRUB menu every time I turn my computer on and then manually select the option that works.

Is there a way to run the version I want it to run automatically? I would love it to boot into it automatically so I don't have to spam ESC every time I turn my computer on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry) - This question has been asked and answered, you were just using the wrong terms. The choices you are making are not the GRUB version, they are different kernel versions. Please consider filing a bug report about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
```

then command: sudo update_grub

Comment: Thanks, that worked and solved what I was trying to do.