# NVIDIA drivers installation issues on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

So far, I have tried to install the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 a number of ways but none has worked so far and I don't know where else to look for a solution.

## Attempt 1

First, I purged all NVIDIA & CUDA:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
```

Then, I followed the instructions from [NVIDIA website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local):

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.0.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local_12.0.1-525.85.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-0-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

## Attempt 2

Downloaded the runfile:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.0.1/local_installers/cuda_12.0.1_525.85.12_linux.run

sudo init 3
```

exit GUI by pressing CTRL + ALT + F2

run `sudo sh cuda_12.0.1_525.85.12_linux.run`

## Attempt 3

Used Software & Updates tool:
[image]

The latest attempt produced the following log:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sat Feb 25 08:18:52 2023
installer version: 525.85.12

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer
    --ui=none
    --no-questions
    --accept-license
    --disable-nouveau
    --no-cc-version-check
    --install-libglvnd

Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 525.85.12.
-> An alternate method of installing the NVIDIA driver was detected. (This is usually a package provided by your distributor.) A driver installed via that method may integrate better with your system than a driver installed by nvidia-installer.

Please review the message provided by the maintainer of this alternate installation method and decide how to proceed:

The NVIDIA driver provided by Ubuntu can be installed by launching the "Software & Updates" application, and by selecting the NVIDIA driver from the "Additional Drivers" tab.


(Answer: Continue installation)
WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are already present at: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf, /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be sure you have rebooted your system since these files were written.  If you have rebooted, then Nouveau may be enabled for other reasons, such as being included in the system initial ramdisk or in your X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
-> For some distributions, Nouveau can be disabled by adding a file in the modprobe configuration directory.  Would you like nvidia-installer to attempt to create this modprobe file for you? (Answer: Yes)
-> One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau have been written.  For some distributions, this may be sufficient to disable Nouveau; other distributions may require modification of the initial ramdisk.  Please reboot your system and attempt NVIDIA driver installation again.  Note if you later wish to re-enable Nouveau, you will need to delete these files: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf, /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="/usr/bin/cc".
-> Performing CC check.
ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path' command line option.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Based on the log, I guess there is an issue with kernel. I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

I get the following:

Reading package lists... Done

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-5.18.10-051810-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I would be thankful for any suggestion about installing the driver on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: changing the kernel to 5.15.0-60-generic fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The key was being able to install Linux headers with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

As it wasn't able to install the headers for the kernel, it produced the following log:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-5.18.10-051810-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Therefore, I tried to change the kernel to 5.15.0-60, rerun `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r and retried the driver installation with **Attempt 3**. I believe other attempts listed above would also work after changing the kernel.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry) is the link with the explanation about how to set up the default kernel.