# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

After a manual restart that I did because of my Ubuntu screen not reacting I got the following output:

[image: Screen while booting Ubuntu]

After this message is being shown the process gets stuck. I can't interact with the cli. I always need to reboot manually.

The hardware is the same before and after this error.

I need to get my Ubuntu operating system to being able to boot again.

Comment: Are you on a dual boot? Then you can see the grub boot menu during boot. Select advanced options, and boot with an older kernel.

Comment: If you are not on a dual boot manually open the grub menu (`Shift` in BIOS and `Esc` in UEFI), and boot with an older kernel. Then, apply all upgrades, and reboot

Comment: If you are unable to access the grub menu, you will have to boot with a live USB, chroot to your Ubuntu install (you can google how to), and then apply all updates properly using chroot.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yes I have a dual-boot. When I open the cli via hitting "C"-Key I see the grub cli. I tries to follow these instructions for starting with an older kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry

But I cant event change the directory via "cd" - i always get the error: "error: can't find command".

Comment: The cd command is supposed top work after opening ubuntu. Instead, can you go to Advanced option for Ubuntu in the dual boot menu? You will find older kernels in there