# 'Your GPU memory is full' error in DaVinci Resolve, Ubuntu 22.04, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, changing kernels didn't solve it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, video-editor, davinci-resolve

I'm trying to get DaVinci Resolve running for the first time. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. Initially I was getting an error about GPU processing mode before the program would even open.

After some tweaking I got rid of that one but now I'm getting a 'Your GPU memory is full' whenever I start a timeline, and although I can see the videos I load on the thumbnail, they don't show up in the window where they are supposed to.

I have tried upgrading the NVIDIA drivers, changing kernel to HWE, back to GA (as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488785/in-mate-22-04-davinci-18-6-2-returns-your-gpu-memory-is-full-despite-nvidi)), and doing multiple runs of purging and installing the drivers, CUDA, the headers, and the nvidia linux modules.

The output of nvidia-smi:

```
Tue Jan  2 14:10:18 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.08              Driver Version: 545.23.08    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060        On  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   70C    P8               7W /  88W |    229MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3548      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           45MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6251      C   /opt/resolve/bin/resolve                    180MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(not sure why it shows 545, I have 535 installed)

Output of nvcc --version:

```
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

uname -r:

`5.15.0-91-generic`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the newer kernel flavors too? I did a test about a month ago to see if the newer updates work again, and they did (currently running `6.2.0.39.generic` with no issues. My system is also still running `nvidia-smi 535.146.02` (different GPU though), so maybe the 545 you're seeing as a return of `nvidia-smi` could be contributing to your issues?

Answer (score 3):

- Uninstall / reinstall 535 driver
- Reboot
- NVIDIA X Server Settings > PRIME profiles > **Performance Mode**
- Reboot

I faced this issue recently when an `apt upgrade` messed up my drivers. After reinstalling I kept getting the "GPU memory full" error and Resolve wouldn't work properly. Turns out reinstalling the driver had reset the PRIME profile, and switching back to performance mode fixed it for me.