linux kernel gives problem when booting
I have an issue with the linux kernel of my laptop. If I switch on the computer, when it arrives to the user screen, after 1-2 seconds before I could enter the password, the screen becomes fully black. The only thing I can do is to force switching off the computer.
I am running ubuntu 22.04 and my problem started with the linux kernel version 5.15.0-86 generic. The version 5.15.0-84 works fine.
Any idea why this may be happening?

https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+recovery+mode - then scrutinize /var/log files, dmesg | less might be a start.

What should I expect to find in that massive amount of information?

less filename or zcat filename | less will show the content of the files, (zcat for *.gz files). As less is running, hit h to see the help for less, in there you find / for search/find - use it to look for keywords as; error, fail, warning and so on. EDIT your question and add any additional info you find there (i.e. NOT in comments).

See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/216398/289138 for avoiding the problem, at least for the time being.

Thanks I will try that!!!

I suggest that you update with the latest HWE kernel, which will probably make this problem go away.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
Normally LTS installs get this automatically in time. Are you doing full system updates? From the CLI, it is the following command:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y


Copilot also recommended me to do that (bad idea to follow MS AI to solve linux problems) and now I have one more problem. The working kernel now gives me problems with something call snap. But I does not seem a big deal for the moment.
