How to make a given kernel line default on Ubuntu 20.04?
I have two kernel "flavors" installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 system: linux-generic and linux-generic-hwe-20.04.
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-generic | grep '^ii'
ii  linux-generic                                               5.4.0.182.180                               amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                                     5.15.0.107.117~20.04.1                      amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers

I need both of them because some vendor packages only support 5.4 kernels and I have other projects that need kernels 5.15+.
The problem is that the hwe kernels are boot by default if I don't stop and select the generic 5.4 kernel on boot menu. I would like to make the 5.4 kernels linux-generic as default.
I know that you can make a specific kernel version/package default on grub but I don't want to be changing the default kernel every time a new patch update is installed.
How to achieve that with grub? Is it possible?
Thank you.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry

Problem is that even using the classname, you are always referring to a specific kernel like 5.15.0-107 and not the latest from hwe or lts.
